# Matcher.appendReplacement with literal text

Tags: java, regex

I am using [Matcher.appendReplacement()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) and it worked great until my replacement string had a $2 in it:

> Note that backslashes ( \ ) and dollar
>   signs ($) in the replacement string
>   may cause the results to be different
>   than if it were being treated as a
>   literal replacement string. Dollar
>   signs may be treated as references to
>   captured subsequences as described
>   above, and backslashes are used to
>   escape literal characters in the
>   replacement string.

Is there a convenience method somewhere that will escape all backslashes \ and dollar signs $ with a backslash? Or do I have to write one myself? It sounds like it's not that hard, just would be nice if they gave you one >:(

**edit:** since they do give you one, I need to `replace(">:(", ":-)");`

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java to me.

Comment: NOTE: This is not a duplicate of "How to escape text for regular expression in Java".

Comment: Sorry about that. I saw that the #2 answer showed how to use quoteReplacement and didn't bother to read the whole thing.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [Matcher.quoteReplacement](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)) on the replacement string.

Unfortunately "ease of use" in this case conflicts with strong typing. [Explanation: An object of Java static type `java.lang.String` is any immutable sequence of `char`s. It doesn't tell you the format of that raw data. In this scenario we have text probably meaningful to the user, text encoded in a mini-language for replacement and text encoded in a mini-language for the pattern. The Java type system has no way of distinguishing these (although you can do fun things with annotation-based type checkers, often to avoid XSS or SQL/command injection vulnerabilities). For the pattern mini-language you can to a form of conversion with `Pattern.compile` although that is a specific use and most APIs methods ignore it (for ease of use). An equivalent `ReplacementText.compile` could be written. Further, you could ignore the mini-languages and go for libraries as "DSLs". But all this doesn't help casual ease of use.]

Comment: Hey, all right! How did I miss that from the Javadoc?!?!?!?!!

Comment: "Unfortunately "ease of use" in this case conflicts with strong typing." how so?

Comment: Yeah.. could you clarify what the "ease of use / strong typing" note means?

Answer (score 19):

Here's another option:

```
matcher.appendReplacement(stringbuffer, "");
stringbuffer.append(replacement);
```

`appendReplacement()` handles the job of copying over the text between the matches, then `StringBuffer#append()` adds your replacement text *sans* adulterations.  This is especially handy if you're generating the replacement text dynamically, as in Elliott Hughes' [Rewriter](http://elliotth.blogspot.com/2004/07/java-implementation-of-rubys-gsub.html).

Comment: This is certainly the best solution, no need to parse and escape the replacement string.

Comment: Nice and easy. Thanks!

Comment: Genius solution.  Far more elegant than having to worry about escaping.

Answer (score 5):

I got it to work with the following, but I like Tom Hawtin's solution better :-)

```
private static Pattern escapePattern = Pattern.compile("\\$|\\\\");
replacement = escapePattern.matcher(replacement).replaceAll("\\\\$0");
matcher.appendReplacement(stringbuffer, replacement);
```

Tom's solution:

```
matcher.appendReplacement(stringbuffer, Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement));
```