# Regular Expression using User String

Tags: java

I want to convert an incoming user string into a regular expression, and the incoming string may contain whitespace. Is there a way to ignore all whitespace within the string?

Comment: Also, I'm already using Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE. Doesn't seem like I can use multiple flags?

Comment: You can use multiple flags using the | (single bar) operator. like `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.COMMENTS`. You can see more examples of this at [this link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html)

Comment: Ok thanks, I was using + instead. Bad mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in using the [COMMENTS](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#COMMENTS) flag in the `Pattern` class, which:

> Permits whitespace and comments in
>   pattern. In this mode, whitespace is
>   ignored, and embedded comments
>   starting with # are ignored until the
>   end of a line.

You can find more info on using flags with Patterns [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html).

An alternative is to just remove the whitespace before compiling your regex by using either [String.replace](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) or [String.replaceAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

@Zach L and @smas answered your real question

> I want to convert an incoming user string into a regular expression ...

I want to warn you to be cautious.  It is easy to write a pathological regex that can consume vast amounts of CPU time for certain input strings.  If you allow users to enter arbitrary regexes themselves, there is a risk that they will enter a pathological regex, either by accident, or with the intention of overloading your service ...

Comment: This deserves some attention. We wouldn't want little Bobby Tables coming in!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will be good to you:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("...", Pattern.COMMENTS)
```

Pattern.COMMENTS means:

> Permits whitespace and comments in
>   pattern.  In this mode, whitespace is
>   ignored, and embedded comments
>   starting with # are ignored until the
>   end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression replacement (see http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=145832) to remove the spaces.  If you are converting user input to a regular expression, be very careful about escaping (it is like SQL is that users can put in metacharacters that will make your program misbehave); you can get information on proper escaping [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java).