# How to escape regex text in Java for POSIX Extended format

Tags: java, regex, posix-ere

I want to quote a piece of string to be treated as a literal string inside a larger regex expression, and that expression needs to conform to the [POSIX Extended Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions) format.

This question is very similar to [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java), except that the answer there does not satisfy me since it proposes I use `Pattern.quote()`, which relies on the special `\Q` and `\E` marks - those are supported by Java regexes but do **not** conform to the POSIX Extended format.

For example, I want `one.two` to become `one\.two` and not `\Qone.two\E`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by Brian can be simplified to

```
String toBeEscaped = "\\{}()[]*+?.|^$";
return inString.replaceAll("[\\Q" + toBeEscaped + "\\E]", "\\\\$0");
```

Tested with `"one.two"` only.

Comment: How do you mean it? It works for all examples I can come with.

Comment: @Sean: It replaces one character *at a time*, but `replaceAll()` iterates through all the characters in the string.  It does take a ridiculous amount of code to replace that one character, though.  I've always just done it @Brian's way; it's *so* much easier to read.

Comment: I was hoping there's a built-in method of doing this... but it looks like I'll have to write it on my own or just use your very concise solution, thank you.

Comment: @Oak There's j.u.r.Pattern.RemoveQEQuoting() doing something like this, but it's private and specialized. @Alan I think Brian's code is neither easier to read nor faster. Of course, the former is subjective and the latter would need some microbenchmarking.

Comment: `RemoveQEQuoting()` is only there to fix a bug in the original implementation.  Ironically, that bug manifested only when `\Q` and `\E` were used inside character classes, as your solution does.

Comment: [Here you go.](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6173522) The bug report doesn't discuss the solution, but if you look at the source for JDK 1.5 you'll see that it treats `\Q...\E` as described in the report; `RemoveQEQuoting()` was added in JDK 1.6 ("mustang").

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something along these lines:

```
// untested
String escape(String inString)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(inString.length() * 2);
    String toBeEscaped = "\\{}()[]*+?.|^$";

    for (int i = 0; i < inString.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = inString.charAt(i);

        if (toBeEscaped.contains(c))
        {
            builder.append('\\');
        }

        builder.append(c);
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: The method name should be lower case, this is not C#. Otherwise: +1

Comment: @Sean Patrick: Fair point, I don't write much Java these days :)