# String.split() *not* on regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

Since `String.split()` works with regular expressions, this snippet:

```
String s = "str?str?argh";
s.split("r?");
```

... yields: `[, s, t, , ?, s, t, , ?, a, , g, h]`

What's the most elegant way to split this String on the `r?` sequence so that it produces `[st, st, argh]`?

**EDIT**: I know that I can escape the problematic `?`. The trouble is I don't know the delimiter offhand and I don't feel like working this around by writing an `escapeGenericRegex()` function.

Comment: This is mentioned in the accepted answer of [How to split a string in Java - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3481828). Related questions: How to split string by [(space)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7899525)/[(backslash)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23751618)/[(newline)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/454908)/[(pipe)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10796160)? ; [How to escape text for regular expression in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

A general solution using just Java SE APIs is:

```
String separator = ...
s.split(Pattern.quote(separator));
```

The `quote` method returns a regex that will match the argument string as a literal.

Comment: This operation create `Matcher` at every call. 
If you repeat this action, its better prepare one `Matcher m = Pattern.compile(separator, Pattern.LITERAL)`

Answer (score 13):

You can use

```
StringUtils.split("?r")
```

from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

Comment: StringUtils.split() should be much faster than String.split() since StringUtils.split is using linear scanning for the separator, whereas String.split() is using regex, which is really slow

Comment: Something to be aware of - according to the JavaDoc this treats adjacent separators as one separator. In my situation this was not desired

Comment: be aware that this accepts a list of _characters_ to split on, not a string. so this would split the string on instances of `?` or `r`, not instances of `r?`

Comment: No reference to the String we are splitting, `s`?

Comment: This is missing the first argument, and moreover would not produce the desired output anyway.  It splits on every character, not the whole string.  Use `StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator(s, "r?")`.

Answer (score 6):

This works perfect as well:

```
public static List<String> splitNonRegex(String input, String delim)
{
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    int offset = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        int index = input.indexOf(delim, offset);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            l.add(input.substring(offset));
            return l;
        } else
        {
            l.add(input.substring(offset, index));
            offset = (index + delim.length());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The performance of this solution is not ideal since it creates temporary substrings.

Comment: @BladeCoder: You're right. I fixed it :) (When I wrote this, I must have been 16, I guess)

Comment: Much better indeed :)

Comment: I have an app (and tests) where I split frequently, and I do not need a single split on a regular expression. And Android-Studio keeps kvetching about my regular expressions (which I do not need) are not efficiently pre-compiled patterns. I will use this, and not use it in the production code inside a loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Escape the `?`:

```
s.split("r\\?");
```

Comment: a more generic solution was asked

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] strs = str.split(Pattern.quote("r?"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Using directly the Pattern class, is possible to define the expression as LITERAL, and in that case, the expression will be evaluated as is (not regex expression).

```
Pattern.compile(<literalExpression>, Pattern.LITERAL).split(<stringToBeSplitted>);
```

example:

```
String[] result = Pattern.compile("r?", Pattern.LITERAL).split("str?str?argh");
```

will result:

```
[st, st, argh]
```

Comment: Your answer would be best if you explained your code.  It will also be more useful to new users who search something similar in the future.

Comment: I think that `Pattern.quote(...)` is a better solution.  Certainly it is fewer characters :-)

Comment: There should be no difference in performance.  They will do the same thing under the hood.

Comment: I have to agree with you. In theory, LITERAL should be more performant than evaluate the regex expression, but I done a little test with java 8, and for some inputs, LITERAL was best than QUOTE, but for others was the reverse. Conclusion: for now there is no relevant difference on performance.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Guava Splitter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html):

> Extracts non-overlapping substrings from an input string, typically by recognizing appearances of a separator sequence. This separator can be specified as a single character, fixed string, regular expression or CharMatcher instance. Or, instead of using a separator at all, a splitter can extract adjacent substrings of a given fixed length.

Answer (score 2):

`org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` has methods for splitting Strings without expensive regular expressions.

Be sure to read the javadocs closely as the behavior can be subtle.   `StringUtils.split` (as in another answer) does not meet the stated requirements.  Use `StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator` instead:

```
String s = "str?str?argh";

StringUtils.split(s, "r?");                   //[st, st, a, gh]
StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator(s, "r?");   //[st, st, argh]
```