# How to split a String by space

Tags: java, string, split, arrays

I need to split my String by spaces.
For this I tried:

```
str = "Hello I'm your String";
String[] splited = str.split(" ");
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Looks good... what are the values in the 'splited' array?

Comment: Your code does indeed work as-is. See [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/KSQboC).

Comment: @BasilBourque - I couldn't find any run button on that link

Comment: @nanosoft The page at IdeOne.com runs automatically upon loading. See output below the code, in *stdout* section. To alter the code, click the `fork` link near top left corner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)

Answer (score 823, accepted):

What you have should work. If, however, the spaces provided are defaulting to... something else? You can use the whitespace regex:

```
str = "Hello I'm your String";
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
```

This will cause any number of consecutive spaces to split your string into tokens.

Comment: what regular expression to use if we have to split on these space , + - / ;

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head. If it's only space, you can form your own class by bracketing it, so in your case probably (note, this is untested)  `[ +\\-/;]+` - notice the `\\` around the `-` to escape it. Now, this will probably match `This is+a+ - + - + - test` into 4 tokens, which may or may not be desired. The real problem is you can't use `\\s` to match "any whitespace". You might be better off not using split, and just using `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z0-9]+)").matcher(text); while(m.find()) list.add(m.group(1));` to fetch words instead of splitting a big text.

Comment: @FarazAhmad Note that those are just off the top of my head, there could be little bugs, so don't copy/paste the code in that comment :)

Comment: string.split("\\s+")[0] - gets only the first part

Comment: @Combine while that's true, I'd recommend against it - often you need the rest of the array too, and I'd hate for someone to be like `for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) System.out.println(string.split("\\s+")[i]);` or something silly like that. I'd rather see `String[] splited = string.split("\\s+"); String first = splited[0];`

Comment: Be aware that compiling regex is costly. It is better to generate the pattern upfront. (see gjain's example).

Comment: @Jotschi That's known as a "microoptimization" - I would not be the least concerned that it's too expensive until you've identified that it is so.

Comment: I find it useful as my use case was to split the string and remove multiple spaces. One line of code does both for me.

Comment: What If I want to have `List<String>` as a result (cause in general we should prefer `List` to arrays). Of course I can convert, but can I parse directly to `List` avoiding intermediate array?

Comment: @javapowered I wish I had a Christmas present for you. But I don't. Your best bet is `Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s+"));` - or maybe `Stream.of(str.split("\\s+"))` and do something with the stream.

Comment: be aware that for Kotlin you need to use `"\\s+".toRegex()`

Answer (score 138):

While the accepted answer is good, be aware that you will end up with a leading empty string if your input string starts with a white space. For example, with:

```
String str = " Hello I'm your String";
String[] splitStr = str.split("\\s+");
```

The result will be:

```
splitStr[0] == "";
splitStr[1] == "Hello";
splitStr[2] == "I'm";
splitStr[3] == "Your";
splitStr[4] == "String";
```

So you might want to trim your string before splitting it:

```
String str = " Hello I'm your String";
String[] splitStr = str.trim().split("\\s+");
```

[edit]

In addition to the `trim` caveat, you might want to consider the unicode non-breaking space character (`U+00A0`). This character prints just like a regular space in string, and often lurks in copy-pasted text from rich text editors or web pages. They are not handled by `.trim()` which tests for characters to remove using `c <= ' '`; `\s` will not catch them either.

Instead, you can use `\p{Blank}` but you need to enable unicode character support as well which the regular `split` won't do. For example, this will work: `Pattern.compile("\\p{Blank}", UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).split(words)` but it won't do the `trim` part.

The following demonstrates the problem and provides a solution. It is *far* from optimal to rely on regex for this, but now that Java has 8bit / 16bit byte representation, an efficient solution for this becomes quite long.

```
public class SplitStringTest {
    static final Pattern TRIM_UNICODE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^\\p{Blank}*(.*)\\p{Blank}*$", UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
    static final Pattern SPLIT_SPACE_UNICODE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\p{Blank}+", UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);

    public static String[] trimSplitUnicodeBySpace(String str) {
        Matcher trimMatcher = TRIM_UNICODE_PATTERN.matcher(str);
        boolean ignored = trimMatcher.matches();
        return SPLIT_SPACE_UNICODE_PATTERN.split(trimMatcher.group(1));
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String words = " Hello    I'm\u00A0your String\u00A0";
        // non-breaking space here --^ and there -----^

        String[] split = words.split(" ");
        String[] trimAndSplit = words.trim().split(" ");
        String[] splitUnicode = SPLIT_SPACE_UNICODE_PATTERN.split(words);
        String[] trimAndSplitUnicode = trimSplitUnicodeBySpace(words);

        System.out.println("words: [" + words + "]");
        System.out.println("split: [" + String.join("][", split) + "]");
        System.out.println("trimAndSplit: [" + String.join("][", trimAndSplit) + "]");
        System.out.println("splitUnicode: [" + String.join("][", splitUnicode) + "]");
        System.out.println("trimAndSplitUnicode: [" + String.join("][", trimAndSplitUnicode) + "]");
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
words: [ Hello    I'm your String ]
split: [][Hello][][][][I'm your][String ]
trimAndSplit: [Hello][][][][I'm your][String ]
splitUnicode: [][Hello][I'm][your][String]
trimAndSplitUnicode: [Hello][I'm][your][String]
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I was running into an exception because of leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: String str = " Hello <space><space><space>I'm your String";, you will get [Hello][][][I'm your][String ], but we only want [Hello][I'm][your][String]

Comment: @steven You are absolutely right, thanks for pointing this out! I fixed the proposed solution, the regex was simply missing a `+`

Answer (score 32):

I do believe that putting a regular expression in the str.split parentheses should solve the issue. The Java String.split() method is based upon regular expressions so what you need is:

```
str = "Hello I'm your String";
String[] splitStr = str.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 15):

Use `Stringutils.split()` to split the string by whites paces. For example `StringUtils.split("Hello World")` returns "Hello" and "World";

In order to solve the mentioned case we use split method like this

```
String split[]= StringUtils.split("Hello I'm your String");
```

when we print the split array the output will be :

Hello

I'm

your

String

[For complete example demo check here](http://java-interview-questions.com/how-to-separate-strings-in-java-by-spaces-with-example)

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
String[] splited = str.split("\\s");
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html

Answer (score 8):

if somehow you don't wanna use String split method then you can use StringTokenizer class in Java as..

```
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer("Hello I'm your String", " ");
    String[] splited = new String[tokens.countTokens()];
    int index = 0;
    while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
        splited[index] = tokens.nextToken();
        ++index;
    }
```

Comment: There is a possibility of throwing ArrayIndexOutofBounds Exception.

Comment: No, this won't throw "ArrayIndexOutofBounds" because i have declare array size according to number of tokens found in String. this will make sure that arrays size won't be more than received tokens in a string.

Answer (score 7):

Try this one

```
    String str = "This is String";
    String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");

    String split_one=splited[0];
    String split_second=splited[1];
    String split_three=splited[2];

   Log.d("Splited String ", "Splited String" + split_one+split_second+split_three);
```

Answer (score 7):

OK, so we have to do splitting as you already got the answer I would generalize it.

If you want to split any string by spaces, delimiter(special chars).

First, remove the leading space as they create most of the issues.

```
str1 = "    Hello I'm your       String    ";
str2 = "    Are you serious about this question_  boy, aren't you?   ";
```

First remove the leading space which can be space, tab etc.

```
String s = str1.replaceAll("^\\s+","");//starting with whitespace one or more
```

Now if you want to split by space or any special char.

```
String[] sa = s.split("[^\\w]+");//split by any non word char
```

But as w contains [a-zA-Z_0-9] ,so if you want to split by underscore(_) also use

```
 String[] sa = s.split("[!,? ._'@]+");//for str2 after removing leading space
```

Comment: That `replaceAll("^\\s+","")` saved my day. That worked for my case. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

An alternative way would be:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

...

private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");
String[] arr = SPACE.split(str); // str is the string to be split
```

Saw it [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaNetworkWordCount.java)

Answer (score 4):

You can separate string using the below code:

```
   String theString="Hello world";

   String[] parts = theString.split(" ");

   String first = parts[0];//"hello"

   String second = parts[1];//"World"
```

Answer (score 3):

Very Simple Example below:

Hope it helps.

```
String str = "Hello I'm your String";
String[] splited = str.split(" ");
var splited = str.split(" ");
var splited1=splited[0]; //Hello
var splited2=splited[1]; //I'm
var splited3=splited[2]; //your
var splited4=splited[3]; //String
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it's been a while since these answers were posted, here's another more current way to do what's asked:

```
List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputString)) {
    while (sc.hasNext()) output.add(sc.next());
}
```

Now you have a list of strings (which is arguably better than an array); if you do need an array, you can do `output.toArray(new String[0]);`

Comment: How is this at all better than a simple `string.split(" ")`?

Answer (score 2):

Not only white space, but my solution also solves the invisible characters as well.

```
str = "Hello I'm your String";
String[] splited = str.split("\p{Z}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to trim a String that has a "," or white space

```
private String shorterName(String s){
        String[] sArr = s.split("\\,|\\s+");
        String output = sArr[0];

        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple to Spit String by Space**

```
    String CurrentString = "First Second Last";
    String[] separated = CurrentString.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < separated.length; i++) {

         if (i == 0) {
             Log.d("FName ** ", "" + separated[0].trim() + "\n ");
         } else if (i == 1) {
             Log.d("MName ** ", "" + separated[1].trim() + "\n ");
         } else if (i == 2) {
             Log.d("LName ** ", "" + separated[2].trim());
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Join solutions in one!

```
public String getFirstNameFromFullName(String fullName){
    int indexString = fullName.trim().lastIndexOf(' ');
    return (indexString != -1)  ? fullName.trim().split("\\s+")[0].toUpperCase() : fullName.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes for char instead of double

```py
String[] splited = str.split(' ');
```

Comment: Why does single vs double matter? Aren't they the same?

Answer (score 0):

All your need is

org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.split(message, " ")

You need not use trim your string or consider enable unicode character support , and you also could ignore multi-spaces in the string.