# Why can't I get the first and last two characters in two strings for a input box?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the last two characters in a string for inches and the first two characters for feet. Is there something I'm not seeing because I've tried a lot of things.

The heights are supposed to have a space between two sets of numbers something like 5 10 or 12 02 so that's why I'm trying to get certain characters. It's so I can move them into another string to add them together because I'm suppose to add two peoples heights together and this is what I got so far...

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestProgramming
{ //begin class
public static void main(String[] args)
{ // begin main

// ***** variables *****

    int h1;
    int h2;

    String height1 = "0";
    String height2 = "0";

    String  feet1;
    String  feet2;
    String inches1;
    String inches2;

    String FinalFoot = "0";
    String FinalInch = "12";

// ***** input box 1 ***** 

    height1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Please enter the height of the first person in inches.");

// ***** input box 2 ***** 

    height2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Please enter the height of the second person in inches.");  

// ***** parse ***** 

    h1 = Integer.parseInt(height1);
    h2 = Integer.parseInt(height2);

// ***** integer to string *****

    Integer.toString(h1);
    Integer.toString(h2);

// ***** taking the feet and inches from the two heights ***** 

    feet1 = h1.substr(0, 1);            // subtract the last 2 numbers
    inches1 = h1.substr(2, 4);      // subtract the first 2 numbers

    feet2 = h2.substr(0, 1);        // subtract the last 2 numbers
    inches2 = h2.substr(2, 4);      // subtract the first 2 numbers
```

As you can see, I'm having problems where it says "taking the feet and inches from the two heights".

Comment: What's happening that you don't expect?

Comment: I just didn't know why h1 and h2 weren't working and I couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (Note that I hardcoded the inputs for easier testing in a console app)

```
public static void main(String []args){

// removed the early declarations here. This is C-style, old, unnecessary and makes 
// code harder to read

// ***** input box 1 ***** HARCODED - replace with UI call
String height1 = "6 10"; 

// ***** input box 2 ***** HARCODED - replace with UI call
String height2 = "3 10"; 

// ***** parse feet and inches from each input ***** 

String feet1 = height1.substring(0, 1);        // get the first digit
String inches1 = height1.substring(2, 4);      // get the last 2 digits

String feet2 = height2.substring(0, 1);        // get the first digit
String inches2 = height2.substring(2, 4);      // get the last 2 digits

// convert parsed string data to their integer counterparts
int f1 = Integer.parseInt(feet1);
int i1 = Integer.parseInt(inches1);

int f2 = Integer.parseInt(feet2);
int i2 = Integer.parseInt(inches2);

// calculate total feet
int totalFeet = f1 + f2 + (i1 + i2) / 12;

// calculate total inches (using modulus operator)
int totalInches = (i1 + i2) % 12;

// and do the output... assuming this is what you want...
System.out.println(totalFeet + " " + totalInches);
 }
```

Also, it's `substring` not `subtract` or `substr`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a little closer look at the code...

```
int h1;
int h2;

String height1 = "0";
String height2 = "0";

//...

// This is good...
height1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Please enter the height of the first person in inches.");
height2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Please enter the height of the second person in inches.");  

// Ahh, here is a problem...
// If the String values contain any thing that is not a numerical character,
// these will throw a NumberFormatException, meaning anything that follows won't
// be processed...
h1 = Integer.parseInt(height1);
h2 = Integer.parseInt(height2);

// This does nothing.  Integer.toString will RETURN a String representation
// of the int's you pass it, but you're not assigning them to anything...
Integer.toString(h1);
Integer.toString(h2);

// Last time I checked, String don't have a method called `substr`
feet1 = h1.substr(0, 1);
```

Once you have the `String` input from the user, you can use `String#split` to split the input on the spaces, for example...

```
height1 = ...
String[] heightsOf1 = height1.split(" ");
```

You would then need to convert each element into an `int`...

```
int[] personOneHeights = new int[2];
personOneHeights[0] = Integer.parseInt(heightsOf1[0]);
personOneHeights[1] = Integer.parseInt(heightsOf1[1]);
```

Now, you really should add some sanity checking here, you can use `String#contains` to determine if the original `String` contains a space character or not and keep asking the user for input if it doesn't (for example).  You should also check the results of the `split` to determine if it has at least 2 elements in the array.

If you can't use arrays, you shouldn't rely on magic numbers, but try and use the information you have at hand, for example...

```
String part1 = height1.substring(0, height1.indexOf(" "));
String part2 = height1.substring(height1.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the string by spaces first:

[How to split a String by space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899525/how-to-split-a-string-by-space)

```
String[] split1 = height1.split("\\s+");
feet1 = Integer.parseInt( split1[0] );
inches1 = Integer.parseInt( split1[1] );

String[] split2 = height2.split("\\s+");
feet2 = Integer.parseInt( split2[0] );
inches2 = Integer.parseInt( split2[1] );
```

Comment: good catch... I meant to use the strings- height1 and height2

Answer (score 0):

These two lines:

```
Integer.toString(h1);
Integer.toString(h2);
```

don't do what you think they do.

I think you're expecting that after they run, h1 and h2 are now Strings. But that isn't what happens. Variables can't change type. h1 and h2 remain ints.

Rather than having a side effect, `Integer.toString` returns a result. Currently you are simply discarding tht result. You need to do something with the result, such as store it in a new variable. Maybe something like this:

```
String h1AsString = Integer.toString(h1);
String h2AsString = Integer.toString(h2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `substr()` on an `int`. Also, when you call `Integer.toString(h1);` that does not set the variable to a string. To do so, it would have to be:

```
feet1 = Integer.toString(h1)

feet1 = feet1.substr(0, 1);
```

Hope this helps