# How Can I get a specific unknown string which follows a known string in text file?

Tags: android, string

I m new on android and i m not very good at english , so i try to be brief.

I search for hours on internet but get nothing! Here is a file image:

[image]

and I want to retrieve the second string (e.g "12:34:20.421"). please i need your help and excuse me for not putting too much details

Comment: Seems like here is answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899525/how-to-split-a-string-by-space

Comment: Would it always be the second string?

Comment: What have you tried already and where does it fail? Show some code with actual results or errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the dates always going to be 5 characters followed by space? Will January 9 be 01-09? I'm guessing yes. If you've got one line read into a string called someText, then:

```
timeStr = someText.substring(6,12)
```

EDIT: Hah, the OP noted that passing (6,12) was not right [would've been for JavaScript substr()]. It should have been (6,18).

Comment: thanks for your answers ... Yes January 9 is 01-09 and that's what i know on the line , now i want to get the second string which is unknown for me and is in this case "12:34:20.421" for the first line. I need more explanation about your answers , please.

Comment: timeStr = someText.substring(6,12); You'd be taking that entire line into someText. The substring method says to grab characters starting at position 6 (they start at 0), and get 12 characters, the length of your desired time text, stored into timeStr. Try it. And please mark my answer correct, if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bro .. it works fine , but it's rather someText.substring(6,18) instead of Substring(6,12) in my case. thanks again :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the note, and the points. Yeah, I did make a boo-boo there. I was thinking about the JavaScript substr() method. I'll add a correction , for anyone finding this later.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the current time I would simply do something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use regex, I think that there is a better pattern than the one presented here, but it solves the problem.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+).*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("12-25 12:34:20.421 D/CallCard( 3454): updateForegroundCall()...");

    if (m.find()) {
        Log.i(TAG, m.group(1));

    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot !!! so i just want to return the entire second string , 12:34:20.421 in this case .So What have i to do ?  what does m.group(1) exactly return ? i guess 12 (not the first one but the second) in that case , isn't it?

Comment: `m.group(1)` returns the whole time entry, in this case 12:34:20.421