# Split string not working properly

Tags: java, string, split

I have trouble splitting a name by a space, and I can't seem to figure out why. Could someone please provide me with a solution?

My code is like this:

```
 public void getPlayerNames(int id){
    try {
        Document root = Jsoup.connect("http://www.altomfotball.no/element.do?cmd=team&teamId=" + id).get();
        Element table = root.getElementById("sd_players_table");
        Elements names = table.getElementsByTag("a");

        for(Element name : names){
            getPlayers().add(new Player(name.text()));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

which returns the name of football players as a string. The names are retrieved such as Mario Balotelli, Steven Gerrard, and so on, and I assumed I could use string.split(" "); to get me the first and last names, but whenever I try to access the second space of the string array it gives me an index out of bounds exception. Here is the code trying to fetch me the first name

```
/**
 * Method to get the first name of a player
 */
public static String getFirstName(String name){
    String[] nameArray = name.split(" ");
    return nameArray[0];
}
```

Thanks for answers!

Sindre M

EDIT ######
So I got it to work, but thanks for the effort. The problem was that even though I could not see it in a simple sysout statement, the names actually contained a "&nbsp"; character, so I solved it by running a replaceAll("&nbsp ;" , " ") on the names for a better formatting.

Comment: Can you show a runable example?

Comment: try to print the name before splitting as it might not have space in it.

Comment: did you check with logging what the name is? If there is no space in the `String name` there is no `nameArray[1]` (second part what gives the array out of bound exception)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to write a screen-scraper you need to be more defensive in your code... Definitely test the length of the array first and log any unexpected inputs so you can incorporate them later...

```
public static String getFirstName(String name) {
    String[] nameArray = name.split(" ");
    if (nameArray.length >= 1) {  // <== check length before you access nameArray[0]  
        return nameArray[0];   
    } else {
        // log error
    }
    return null;
}
```

Additionally java.util.Optional in Java 8 provides a great alternative to returning null...

```
public static Optional<String> getFirstName(String name) {
    String[] nameArray = name.split(" ");
    if (nameArray.length >= 1) {
        return Optional.of(nameArray[0]);
    } else {
        // log error
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: actually nameArray[0] will **always** be there(if no nullpointer is thrown), even if there was no split done.  It's nameArray[1] who gave the index out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting   in the actual string as you are retrieving from html page. try to debug and check.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.appkart.examples;

public class SplitProgram {

    public void firstNameArray(String nameString) {
        String strArr[] = nameString.split(",");

        for (String name : strArr) {
            String playerName = name.trim();
            String firstName = playerName.substring(0, playerName.indexOf(" "));
            System.out.println(firstName);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nameString = "Mario Balotelli, Steven Gerrard";
        SplitProgram program = new SplitProgram();
        program.firstNameArray(nameString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the correct answer should be:

```
   String[] nameArray = name.split("\\s+");
```

But to be honest, there are couple of answers at stackoverflow. 
Eg.

[How to split a String by space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899525/how-to-split-a-string-by-space)

[How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)

Answer (score 0):

First try to replace white space as

```
string.replace(" ","");
```

then try to split with [,] as

```
String strAr[] = string.split(",");
```

Comment: what happens if the string  already contains character ',' . Ex : "jhone,j wick"  jhone,j should be the first name.?

by the way your first line should be string.replace(" ",","); 

',' missing

Comment: You are write, if name contains [,] there will be a problem but i don't think it will happen. Bcz  the sample shared in the questions such as Mario Balotelli, Steven Gerrard, and so on. Assuming there will not be any such string.