# How to split a string with space being the delimiter using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to split the input sentence based on space between the words. It is not working as expected.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scaninput=new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputSentence = scaninput.next();
    String[] result=inputSentence.split("-");
    // for(String iter:result) {
    //     System.out.println("iter:"+iter);
    // }
    System.out.println("result.length: "+result.length);
    for (int count=0;count<result.length;count++) {
        System.out.println("==");
        System.out.println(result[count]);
    }
}
```

It gives the output below when I use "-" in split:

```
fsfdsfsd-second-third
result.length: 3
==
fsfdsfsd
==
second
==
third
```

When I replace "-" with space " ", it gives the below output.

```
first second third
result.length: 1
==
first
```

Any suggestions as to what is the problem here? I have already referred to the stackoverflow post [How to split a String by space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899525/how-to-split-a-string-by-space), but it does not work.

Using `split("\\s+")` gives this output:

```
first second third
result.length: 1
==
first
```

Comment: Try using `\\s+` if there are multiple spaces. Show us what have you tried *exactly*.

Comment: This is the output first second third
result.length: 1
==
first

Comment: added the same in my question for better view. Not able to format in comment

Comment: Show the modified code.. Put it in your program. the entire code..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
scanner.next()
```

To

```
scanner.nextLine()
```

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#)

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

Calling `next()` returns the next *word*.
Calling `nextLine()` returns the next *line*.

Answer (score 7):

The `next()` method of `Scanner` already splits the string on spaces, that is, it returns the next token, the string until the next string. So, if you add an appropriate `println`, you will see that `inputSentence` is equal to the first word, not the entire string.

Replace `scanInput.next()` with `scanInput.nextLine()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `scaninput.next()` will only read until the first whitespace character, so it's only pulling in the word `first`. So the `split` afterward accomplishes nothing.

Instead of using `Scanner`, I suggest using `java.io.BufferedReader`, which will let you [read an entire line at once](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29).

Comment: Well scanner isn't wrong, he just needs to use `nextLine()` or change the deliminator.

Comment: which one is better ? Scanner or bufferedReader?

Answer (score 0):

One more alternative is to go with buffered Reader class that works well.

```
String inputSentence;

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            inputSentence=br.readLine();

            String[] result=inputSentence.split("\\s+");
rintln("result.length: "+result.length);

            for(int count=0;count<result.length;count++)
            {
                System.out.println("==");
                System.out.println(result[count]);
            }

        }
```