# Initialize an sqlite table through an array contained in a xml resource

Tags: java, android, sqlite, initialization

I have to initialize a sqllite database in android.
Here is the structure of the table:

```
    public static abstract class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "entryid";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
}
```

I have an array.xml file like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string-array name="my_array">

    <item>S1 999</item>
    <item>S1 10</item>
    <item>S1 111</item>
    <item>S1 101</item>

</string-array>
```

Now I want to take the items in this resource, split them into two and use the result to initialize my database. I have a function which should do the trick:

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    Resources res = fContext.getResources();
    String[] myArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.my_array);
    for (String item : myArray){
        System.out.println(item);
        String[] split = item.split(" ");
        values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID, split[1]);
        values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, split[0]);
        db.insert(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
```

The problem is that instead of getting the expected result

```
S1 999 
S1 10 
S1 111 
S1 101
```

I get the following:

```
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
```

In fact, each item printed by `System.out.println(item);` consists of a pair of two value, like `1 1, 2 1` and so on. How should I modify the java method onCreate to get the correct couple of strings, like `S1 999`?

Here is how I read the data in the table:

```
String[] projection = {
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID,
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE,
    };
Cursor cursor = db.query(
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,  // The table to query
            projection,                               // The columns to return
            null,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
            null,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                                     // don't group the rows
            null,                                    // don't filter by row groups
            sortOrder 


);


String result = "";

    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);
    int iRow = cursor.getColumnIndex(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID);
    int iName = cursor.getColumnIndex(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE); 
        for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
        result = result + cursor.getString(iRow) + " " + cursor.getString(iName) + "\n";
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

: I have a cursor which sends a request to the database, and then I print the content of the cursor.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899525/how-to-split-a-string-by-space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899525/how-to-split-a-string-by-space)

Comment: @MD this was a small problem, thanks. However, I still have the main problem of the wrong output..

Comment: Make ArrayList<String> and add elements one by one and check.

Comment: how are you fetching your data and printing it? post code.

Comment: @Rahul I have added more explanation...

Comment: what are the columns in `projection` :)

Comment: I have added them..is it there the problem?

Comment: why not try using hashmap after the split to store values? that would be pretty easier to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are splitting your string incorrectly. to split a string by space use the below code.

```
str = "This is the string seperated by space";
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
```