# Java equivalent of Python's str.strip().split()?

Tags: java, python

If I had the following

```
str1 = "   Just a test   "
str2 = "                "

l1 = str1.strip().split()
l2 = str2.strip().split()
```

I'd get

```
l1 = ["Just", "a", "test"]
l2 = []
```

How would I accomplish this in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a String by space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899525/how-to-split-a-string-by-space)

Comment: If you start at the javadoc for String, you'd find the answer for yourself in *less* time than it takes to get the answer here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Note for both answers that every call to `split` compiles a new regular expression object. For efficiency, compile it once in advance and place it in a `private static final` field.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`String.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) and [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) (which takes a regular expression). Something like,

```
String str1 = "   Just a test   ";
String str2 = "                ";
String[] l1 = str1.trim().split("\\s+");
String[] l2 = str2.trim().split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(l1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(l2));
```

Outputs (the requested)

```
[Just, a, test]
[]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java's `trim()` and `split("\\s+")`
For example

```
String str1 = "   Just a test   ";
String[] toks = str1.trim().split("\\s+");
```

Then `toks` will be `["Just", "a", "test"]`