# Reading a Multi-line text file with different data in each line

Tags: java

I'm attempting to read a text file with `Scanner dataFile = new Scanner("FileName.txt");` the text file has lines which are supposed to be read for info on them. I'm using:

```
while(dataFile.hasNext()){
      String line = dataFile.nextLine();
      ...
}
```

to loop through the lines. I need to extract a String at the start of the line, an Integer after the String, and a Double after the Integer. They have spaces in-between each part I need to extract so I am willing to \ make a substring search through the line to individually search for the parts in the line.

I am wondering, Is there an easier and quicker method to doing this?

Example contents of text file:

```
Name 10 39.5
Hello 75 87.3
Coding 23 46.1
World 9 78.3
```

Comment: Split the line with spaces as the delimiter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899525/how-to-split-a-string-by-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're all the same format, you can split on whitespace.

```
String str = "Name 10 39.5";
String[] arr = str.split(" ");
String s = arr[0];
int i = Integer.valueOf(arr[1]);
double d = Double.valueOf(arr[2]);
```

Comment: You might want to split on `\\s+`, if there is any chance that there could more than one whitespace character, or whitespace other than space.

Answer (score 0):

```
substring search？
```

you may use

```
String[] str=line.split(" ");

and then str[0] is the string you find
str[1] is the string of Integer ,you cast it
and the str[2] is the string of Double , cast
```