# Find minimum number of a sequence of numbers in a string

Tags: java, string

I am confused as how to separate a sequence of numbers in a string, which are separated by spaces and finding the minimum among them (e.g. "4 3 2 1".)I have an idea of separating the values using a scanner and parsing them, but I don't know how to use them when it's a string. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: split the input string using space into array and then find minimum on them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a String by space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899525/how-to-split-a-string-by-space)

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik how exactly does that post address the _"and finding the minimum among them"_ requirement?

Comment: @Phil the sentence `I have an idea of separating the values using a scanner and parsing them, but I don't know how to use them when it's a string`. I guess OP asked how to split mainly.

Comment: To me that sounds more like _"how do I convert the strings to numbers for comparison"_ but yeah, not enough information

Answer (score 2):

1. Split the string on space (ie `String#split()`)
2. Pass the array to a stream
3. Use `Stream#mapToInt()` with `Integer#parseInt` and then `IntStream#min()` to find the minimum value

For example

```
final String s = "4 3 2 1";
final int min = Arrays.stream(s.split(" "))
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .min()
    .getAsInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//hope this helps

public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "9 3 4 5 7 3 8 9 3 1";
   //split on space
    String[] arr = s.split(" ");

    int result = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]), temp;
    for(int i = 1; i<arr.length; i++) {
                temp = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
    //store lowest in result
        if(result>temp)
            if(temp<result) {
                result = temp;
            }
    }

//print result
System.out.println(result);

}
```

Comment: I have'nt @Phil .... I have downvoted only one and I'm going to comment the reason with that :) and I also know your answer is best on if using java 8.. so Im going to upvote that.. now cheers..

Comment: Fair enough. Just hate seeing a rash of downvotes with no comments

Answer (score 0):

For Splitting the String you can use (For Example):

```
String str = "4 3 2 1";
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
```

as for the individual number in the array "splited" you can use

```
int Num = Integer.parseInt(splited[INDEX]);
```

or you can directly use the `Integer.parseInt(Splited[INDEX])` in the condition of IF loop.

```
int min=Integer.parseInt(splited[0]);
for(int i=1;i<splited.length;i++){
  if(min > Integer.parseInt(splited[i])){
     min = Integer.parseInt(splited[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you converting 'splited' string twice ? once when comparing once when when assigning to min...

Comment: Can you specify where I am converting twice?
And are you the one who down voted mine?

Comment: when you are comparing your current value to min(if condition) you are converting that and if that gives true, again you are converting the same to assign that to min... the better way will be convert it before if block and store it into a variable, compare that variable with min and if true assign the same to min.

Comment: It doesn't Matter, there is no change in the time complexity. What are you trying to prove just specify.
With your approach you are using an extra Int variable which increases the space complexity.

Comment: are you trying to say that using Integer.parseInt(splited[i]) twice for same String will take same time as using Integer.parseInt(splited[i]  once .. why? can you please explain?

Comment: You can try it out your self. By calculating time complexity manually or you can use `import java.util.Timer;` for computation of huge length of the array.
and for your kind information I have specified `int Num = Integer.parseInt(splited[INDEX]);` or  my loop as an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164148/discussion-between-dharmveer-singh-and-ghostranger).

Answer (score -1):

There are parsers for each datatype. In your case you need to parse a string into an int, so do

```
Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Here is the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).