# How to find space separated chars in a string in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

In an application which I continue to develop, I need to find all the space separated chars, which is a word under normal circumstances.
Let me give you an example.

```
This is an e x a m p l e sentence.
```

In the above example, I need to find the *e x a m p l e*.

I've made my search through the SO, but couldn't find a solution to my problem. Most of the similar problems are trying to regex a String and *mask* some of the chars in it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: [split by spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899525/how-to-split-a-string-by-space), find all words with length 1.

Comment: @user202729: Might have a problem with "I am a b a n a n a".

Comment: @hamena314 Then just import a huge English dictionary (and optionally some smart AI to recognize sentence structure...)

Comment: @user202729: Not saying you're wrong. Just pointing out that there are some non-trivial edge cases like the `I` and `a`.

Comment: I c u r a b a n a n a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(?:\w )+\w\b
```

That is - a word boundary, followed by (repeated) single characters and spaces, followed by another character and a word boundary.

https://regex101.com/r/gOXP2w/1

Comment: a problem with "I am a b a n a n a"

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> letters = Arrays.stream(yourString.split(" ").filter(part->part.length()==1).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Step-by-step explanation:

Take your source string, split it at every blank character and put all resulting strings in a string array:

```
String[] parts = yourString.split(" ");
```

The resulting string array currently also contains strings having more than 1 character. So you have to iterate over these strings and remove all those strings that have more than 1 character, so that in the end only strings with a single character will remain. Java8 Streams API allows you to do so in a descriptive way (`Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)` method), so let's transform the string array to a stream of strings:

```
Stream<String> partsStream = Arrays.stream(parts);
```

Now you can filter the stream by calling `Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)` method on this stream - all matching strings will be returned as a new stream. Quick note on predicates: Java interface `java.util.function.Predicate` is a so called 'functional interface', functional interfaces have only one boolean-valued method - in case of Predicate this single method is called `boolean test(T t)`. So for every item in the stream this `test(...)` method will by called to decide wether the item matches a certain condition. A short and descriptive implementation of this predicate can be a so called **lambda expression** (Java8+):

```
// for filtering in the next line, only keep strings with 1 character!
Predicate<String> filterCondition = item -> item.length() == 1;

Stream<String> filteredStream = partsStream.filter(filterCondition);
```

In the end you 'collect' all strings inside the filtered stream into a `java.util.List` of type `java.lang.String`:

```
List<String> letters = filteredStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: a problem with "I am a b a n a n a"