# Display text one by one

Tags: android, textview

The following is my `string`. I would like to display the `string` in `textview` one by one. Means 1st `text` should get replaced by the 2nd in same `textview` and so on. Please suggest me how to do this.

```
String str = "அவனுடைய கையும் இயல்பாக உறைவாளிடம் சென்றது.\nஇந்த சாலை தஞ்சாவூருக்குத்தான் போகிறது.\n" +
            "ஆனால் இதில் முக்கியமானவர்கள் மட்டுமே போகலாம் மற்றவர்களுக்கு வேறு சாலை இருக்கிறது என்றான் வீரன்.\n" +
            "அப்படியா ஆனால் நானும் ரொம்ப ரொம்ப முக்கியமான மனுஷன் தான் என்றான் வந்தியத்தேவன்.";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to add the parameter id to your TextView, for example id1(the name doesn't matter).
Then in your java class you have to do this:

```
TextView text = findViewById(R.id.id1);
// USE THE SPLIT METHOD
String[] strs = str.split("\n");
```

You have to put this lines in the event where you change the text.

```
text.setText(strs[0]);
text.setText(strs[1]);
text.setText(strs[2]);
```

`strs[0]` is அவனுடைய கையும் இயல்பாக உறைவாளிடம் சென்றது.\nஇந்த சாலை தஞ்சாவூருக்குத்தான் போகிறது.

`strs[1]` is ஆனால் இதில் முக்கியமானவர்கள் மட்டுமே போகலாம் மற்றவர்களுக்கு வேறு சாலை இருக்கிறது என்றான் வீரன்.

`strs[2]` is அப்படியா ஆனால் நானும் ரொம்ப ரொம்ப முக்கியமான மனுஷன் தான் என்றான் வந்தியத்தேவன்.

You also can use an int attribute variable and use it in your event, something like this:

```java
// Your class attributes
int i = 0;
//Your event method....
text.setText(strs[i]);
i++;
```

For the 'timer' question you can use a handler, inside your event method something like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   public void run() { 

        if(i<strs.length()){
            text.setText(strs[i]);
            i++;
        }
    } 
}, 5000); // This number is the time in miliseconds
```

This will change your text every 5 seconds.

Comment: I am having two different `textview's` one is to display the above `string`. Other one is to split and display the `string` one by one on `onTouch` event.

Comment: This works fine using for loop. The loop executes fine but displays the last `string` after overriding the other. I want some thing like timer to display the 1st `string` then 2nd and so on

Comment: I edited my answer with and example of the 'timer'

Comment: If it doens't work maybe you need a loop inside the method run

Comment: Thanks I will check with your code and let you know the output.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all you will need to split that string into small strings . You will need an array of strings .

```
String str = "அவனுடைய கையும் இயல்பாக உறைவாளிடம் சென்றது.\nஇந்த சாலை தஞ்சாவூருக்குத்தான் போகிறது.\n" +
            "ஆனால் இதில் முக்கியமானவர்கள் மட்டுமே போகலாம் மற்றவர்களுக்கு வேறு சாலை இருக்கிறது என்றான் வீரன்.\n" +
            "அப்படியா ஆனால் நானும் ரொம்ப ரொம்ப முக்கியமான மனுஷன் தான் என்றான் வந்தியத்தேவன்.";

String[] splitStr = str.split("\\s+");
```

And than you can do whatever you like with that and catch whatever string you want like :

`splitStr[0]` is அவனுடைய

`splitStr[1]` is கையும்

and so on , so forth untill your last one.

After that load it in your TextView , perhaps with a for loop or I don't know when you are going to show it .

```
text.setText(splitStr[1]);
```

Comment: I want to override the 1st `sting` with another **"அவனுடைய கையும் இயல்பாக உறைவாளிடம் சென்றது."** This should get displayed 1st and **இந்த சாலை தஞ்சாவூருக்குத்தான் போகிறது.** This should get overridden in the 1st text.

Comment: ok than you should do it this way
`String[] splitStr = str.split("\\r?\\n");`

Answer (score -1):

```
 private int count = 0;

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(firstString);
        list.add(secondString); //so on
        tvName.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(count < list.size()-1){
                    count = ++count;
                }
                tvName.setText(list.get(count));
                return false;
            }
        });
```

try this.and make sure you add your string into the "list"

Comment: why do you need a list there ? and how do you know how many strings he has ?

Comment: @StavroXhardha cause i think when he + the String like that,there is no way he can get his part of string one by one.

Comment: there is no condition to split his string.so how can he split it into string1,string2.thats what i think

Comment: first of all check my own answer here , and second of all refer to this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899525/how-to-split-a-string-by-space/7899558

Comment: @StavroXhardha rofl :) just because i though he want to set text as the string அவனுடைய கையும் இயல்பாக உறைவாளிடம் சென்றது.\nஇந்த சாலை தஞ்சாவூருக்குத்தான் போகிறது.\n :) sr for dont understand the question :)