# reverse words at even positions only

Tags: java

I've been trying to do this question for a while. It goes as follows:

> Given a string S containing a few words. If the count of words in the string S is even then reverse its even position’s words else reverse its odd position, push reversed words at the starting of a new string and append the remaining words as it is in order.
> For example:

> Input string: Ashish Yadav Abhishek Rajput Sunil Pundir

> Output string: ridnuP tupjaR vadaY Ashish Abhishek Sunil

Do we have to take a string input from user and then convert it into an array and then split it from the middle...? I am very confused. Please give advice.

Comment: Maybe you can take the string as a command line parameter. Maybe you just need to write a function which takes a string parameter. Ask your teacher.

Comment: cannot use command line for this question! its on a coding labs site! @tgdavies

Comment: In which language your trying to this? and you are question is about how to get the input or how to write program for this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure: is this a task that has been given to you by your teacher? Assuming this (because it seems so), I don't provide any actual code snippets, just an idea and you try to solve it at your own. If this is a real task: do not hesitate to ask for a solution but I think with the following context you will be able to do it at your own ; )

1. How you get the string shouldn't matter. For a first test, just
   hardcode it.
2. Split the string at each space ([How to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899525/how-to-split-a-string-by-space)) and safe it in an array.
3. As your array has indexes: use them to check whether it is even or odd (modulo 2) and safe the even- and odd words in extra arrays.
4. From there on you just have to reverse every character in one of your arrays ([In a loop](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/09/java-program-to-reverse-words-in-a-string/) or [with an existing function (recommended)](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-program-to-reverse-each-word-in-string))
5. Now create a string. Fill it according to your instructions (so the reversed strings start at the highest index and decrement. Then add the non-reversed strings, starting at the lowest index and increment).