# Splitting a Java String by the pipe symbol using split("|")

Tags: java, regex, string

The Java official documentation states:

The string `"boo:and:foo"`, for example, yields the following results with these expressions 
Regex   Result
:

```
{ "boo", "and", "foo" }"
```

And that's the way I need it to work. However, if I run this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String test = "A|B|C||D";

        String[] result = test.split("|");

        for(String s : result){
            System.out.println(">"+s+"<");
        }
    }
```

it prints:

```
><
>A<
>|<
>B<
>|<
>C<
>|<
>|<
>D<
```

Which is far from what I would expect:

```
>A<
>B<
>C<
><
>D<
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 454, accepted):

You need

```
test.split("\\|");
```

`split` uses regular expression and in *regex* `|` is a metacharacter representing the `OR` operator. You need to escape that character using `\` (written in String as `"\\"` since `\` is also a metacharacter in String literals and require another `\` to escape it).

You can also use

```
test.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

and let `Pattern.quote` create the escaped version of the regex representing `|`.

Comment: It is, [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method takes regex and `|` is special character for reg ex

Comment: you are my second choice as a moderator on stack overflow. All the best.

Answer (score 42):

Use proper escaping: `string.split("\\|")`

Or, in Java 5+, use the helper [`Pattern.quote()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) which has been created for exactly this purpose:

```
string.split(Pattern.quote("|"))
```

which works with arbitrary input strings. Very useful when you need to quote / escape user input.

Comment: Not shure when the transition was made, but in Java 8, one would use `Pattern.quote()`.

Answer (score 6):

Use this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "A|B|C||D";

    String[] result = test.split("\\|");

    for (String s : result) {
        System.out.println(">" + s + "<");
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is already pointed by accepted answer. No need to repeat it.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the apache library and do this:

```
StringUtils.split(test, "|");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `.split("[|]")`.

(I used this instead of `.split("\\|")`, which didn't work for me.)

Comment: Both versions should work fine. If one doesn't it suggest problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Pshemo This does however add an interesting flavor, that some reserved symbols does not have to be escaped if put inside brackets.

Answer (score 1):

```
test.split("\\|",999);
```

Specifing a **limit** or max will be **accurate** for examples like: "boo|||a" or "||boo|" or " |||"

But  `test.split("\\|");` will return different length strings arrays for the same examples.

use reference: [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/)

Answer (score -2):

the split() method takes a regular expression as an argument