# Java String Split by "|"

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying to parse some data using Java which is separated by '|' sequence. Below is an example of the data.

```
String s = "111206|00:00:00|2|64104|58041";
String [] temp = s.split("|");
for(String p: temp)
System.out.println(p);
```

But instead of splitting at '|' it separates every character separately. Here is the output I get for the above code.

```
 1
 1
 1
 2
 0
 6
 |
 0
 0
 :
 0
 0
 :
 0
 0
 |
 2
 |
 6
 4
 1
 0
 4
 |
 5
 8
 0
 4
 1
```

I found a turn around by replacing the '|' by ',' in the line, but the patch of code is going to run many times and I want to optimize it.

```
 String s = "111206|00:00:00|2|64104|58041";
 s = s.replace('|', ',');
```

I just want to know what the problem is with '|' ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a Java String by the pipe symbol using split("|")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796160/splitting-a-java-string-by-the-pipe-symbol-using-split)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You must use:

```
String [] temp = s.split("\\|");
```

This is because the `split` method takes a regular expression, and `|` is one of the special characters. It means 'or'. That means you are splitting by `'' or ''`, which is just `''`. Therefore it will split between every character.

You need two slashes because the first one is for escaping the actual `\` in the **string**, since `\` is Java's escape character in a string. Java understands the string like "`\|`", and the regex then understands it like "`|`".

Comment: @jahroy [FGITW](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) :)

Comment: Perfect, nicest and easiest way.

Comment: I saw this question 7 mins too late ;-( Good job GoldenDoorknob!

Comment: It was an unexpected behavior!

Comment: Serendipity, by the unexpected split I now know how to get a nice split on every character.  That could be useful someday.