# java split string with regex and store it in variables

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a file and i have to read it line by line. The file contains similar lines, like these:

`asd@lol kek|1.1.1.1
 title@content m e s s a g e|2.3.4.5`

I read these lines to String variables. How can i split these strings to other variables?
For example: var1=title, var2=content, var3=m e s s a g e, var4=2.3.4.5

I tried something like this, but i cant find the solution:

```
stringArray=line.split("|");
```

Comment: You need to clearly identify your delimiters.  Your desired result even is inconsistent, sometimes the space causes a split and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: String has `split` method. Read its documentation and check its overloaded versions (especially `split(regex,limit)`). You can also take a look at `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes.

Comment: About `split("|")` read [Splitting a Java String by the pipe symbol using split(“|”)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796160/splitting-a-java-string-by-the-pipe-symbol-using-split)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex for **matching** and grab the captured groups:

```
^([^@]+)@(\S+)\s([^|]+)\|(.*)$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mW3oJ3/1)

I suggest you read up a bit on difference between `split` and `match` operations.