# Parsing string in java unusual behavior

Tags: java, string, parsing

For some reason this parsing technique doesn't work when I use `"|"` to parse the string.
My java code looks like this

```
public class Testing{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String sentence = "SA|2|What is the capital of Italy|Rome";
        System.out.println(sentence);
        System.out.println("---------------------------");

        String[] tokens = sentence.split("|");
        for(String word: tokens)
            System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

So my output looks like this for some reason

```
SA|2|What is the capital of Italy|Rome
---------------------------
S
A
|
2
|
W
h
a
t

i
s

t
h
e

c
a
p
i
t
a
l
...(and so on)
```

What I want it to do is to display the entire string like this instead of what it is giving me like this

```
SA|2|What is the capital of Italy|Rome
---------------------------
SA
2
What is the capital of Italy
Rome
```

Does anybody know why it is causing every letter to be printed per line and doesn't print it with every word?

Comment: | stands for OR when you are doing the split. try escaping it by doing something like "\\|" truth be told i never had to split anything on a |

Comment: String[] tokens = sentence.split("\\|"); use \\ for special character.

Comment: I tried the ("\\|") and it works! Thank you! If you post it as a question I can mark it as the correct answer!

Comment: I posted an answer, you can up vote it if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reference the following answer on SO

[Splitting a Java String by the pipe symbol using split("|")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796160/splitting-a-java-string-by-the-pipe-symbol-using-split)

you need to say `sentence.split("\\|");` the reason for this is that |, as i mentioned in the comment, is a symbol for OR. Thus, say you wanted to split something on a dot or a white space you would say sentence.split("\.| ")

Comment: Hint: when you already know that it is a duplicate; why didn't you close vote as such?

Comment: Hmm, good point, truth be told not sure how to do it. Just figured i may as well quickly answer it both in comments and as a answer for the benefit of the OP>

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String []args){
    String sentence = "SA|2|What is the capital of Italy|Rome";
    System.out.println(sentence);
    System.out.println("---------------------------");

    String[] tokens = sentence.split("\\|");
    for(String word: tokens){
        System.out.println(word);
    }
 }
```

Use above code. as for special characters escape syntax is required. so use \\ before your special character.

Comment: Hint: answers with just code and no explanations are simply ... not good.

Answer (score 0):

Change the split to

```
final String[] tokens = sentence.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] tokens = sentence.split("\\|");
```

This is work for you.