# Reading Line of String in Text File is Not Consistent

Tags: java, string, split, quartz-scheduler, bufferedreader

**Hi StackOverFlow People,**

I have this issue in my development of System, where I have **4451** lines of record in a **text file**, and I am retrieving it using `BufferedReader` and **split** every line by pipe ( **|** ). I'm using Quartz also to run this reading of file every day. when I test it, I set the quartz job every minute so I can test It if it actually reading the file in every minute. It reads all of the line in the text file by checking it using this.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader((newInputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line = null;
int counter = 0;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    counter++;
}
System.out.println(counter);
```

But when I split the `String`, The result of retrieving `4451` records is inconsistent. Sometimes, It only retrieves 1000+ to 2000+ records, and Sometime it retrieves 4451, but not consistently. This is my code.

```
try {
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader((newInputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line = null;
int counter = 0;
String[] splitLine = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    splitLine = line.split("\\|"); // Splitting the line using '|' Delimiter
    for(String temp : splitLine) {
       System.out.println(temp);
    }
    counter++;
}
System.out.println(counter);
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is the splitting of String and Iterating of the readfile at the same time could be the cause?

**EDIT:**
There's no Exception Occured in the Situation. It Only print the length of by using the `counter` variable.

My Expected Output is *I want to Retrieve all the records per line in the text file and split the string per line by `pipe`.* `counter` is the count of lines retrieved.

Comment: Maybe you're suppressing an exception. Show your full try/catch block. And fix the compile errors.

Comment: Hi @shmosel, I dont have try/catch in that, and there is no error occured.

Comment: There must be a try/catch somewhere. There's nothing wrong with the code you posted. Don't make us beg for a [mcve].

Comment: Do you want to count *lines* **or** do you want to count *tokens*? Please tell us what result you get, and what result you expect. Be **specific**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the result I get is not consistent, I want to read per line and split the line by pipe.

Comment: Your code appears reasonable enough, let's talk about this inconsistency; are you writing to this file while reading?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch No Sir, Im just reading the line `readLine()` and after that Splitting it, and then iterate the elements of String splitted so I can check if it is separated.

Comment: @shmosel Hi Sir, I edit my code and put the Try/Catch, and the only thing the eclipse generated for me to catch is `IOException`.

Comment: Are you confident an exception is not being thrown? Did you check stderr for a stack trace?

Comment: What is `newInputStreamReader`? There isn't enough information here for us to come to a conclusive answer. It could be bad memory on your computer. It could be a bad drive controller. It could be code related.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any error in your code but the code that I have written is working perfectly fine. Here is the code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileReader inputStream = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileReader("Input.txt");
            reader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
            String line = null;
            int counter = 0;
            String[] splitLine = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                splitLine = line.split("\\|"); 
                for (String temp : splitLine) {
                    System.out.println(temp);
                }
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println(counter);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't pipe delimiter be just `"|"` instead of  `"\\|"`?

Try Changing your code to:

```
splitLine = line.split("|"); // Splitting the line using '|' Delimiter
```

Comment: @shadow your answer is plain wrong. Go check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796160/splitting-a-java-string-by-the-pipe-symbol-using-split