# How to extract "Array" from Text file and convert to string

Tags: java

I have a text file which saves my staff details, I want to store the id for future use after login.

I've tried declaring the id after login as `split[0]` but when i call it, it returns null.

This is within the login method in the file `TypoStaff`

```java
String id = split[0];
```

This is my method of calling

```java
TypoStaff s = new TypoStaff();
System.out.println(s.id);
```

I hope to get the result of 0 but I keep getting null.

Comment: What's the code of what you're splitting?

Comment: my text file looks like this
"0|NAME|USERNAME|EMAIL|PASSWORD"

Comment: To get better help provide [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)). Also since your data is in form `foo|bar|baz` take a look at [Splitting a Java String by the pipe symbol using split(“|”)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10796160)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that how you split string. You can try this. this is working.

```
String s = "0|NAME|USERNAME|EMAIL|PASSWORD";
String[] cp=s.split("\\|");
System.out.println(cp[0]);
```