# Issues with splitting JSON string

Tags: java, json

I know its a common question, but I couldn't find information related to my contexts.
First, I am building a String from JSon objects coming from different classes using Gson:

```
String myString= gson.toJson(obj);
String mystring1=gson.toJson(obj1);
```

...

then I am  building a String which I want to deserialize latter on , I use:

```
String serializedString=myString.concat("|" +mystring1);
```

I use | because its not contained in any of the json objects, and I thought that I will I can then easily get an array of strings with:
    String [] arrayOfJsonStrings=serializedString.split("|");
    gson.fromJson(arrayOfJsonStrings[0],obj.class);
    .....

the problem is that
    String [] arrayOfJsonStrings=serializedString.split("|"); is returning empty string, why ?Is there easy way to achieve that ?

Comment: Instead of this fragile, hacky solution, consider doing the safe, secure, simple and robust thing and encode the two strings in a JSON list instead. This will work no matter which characters each object contains.

Answer (score -1):

For one thing you are concatenating your strings two different ways. One of the following would be better and more consistent.

`String serializedString=myString+"|"+mystring1;`

or 
`String serializedString=myString.concat("|").concat(myString1);`

or
`String serializedString=String.format("%s|%s", myString, myString1)`

Your problem is actually the fact that you are splitting on a regex reserved character. You need to escape the split with \ as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796160/splitting-a-java-string-by-the-pipe-symbol-using-split)

`serializedString.split("\\|");`

But I don't really understand why you are doing this anyway? Why not initialize an array with those string values in it?

```
String myString= gson.toJson(obj);
String mystring1=gson.toJson(obj1);
String[] arrayOfJsonStrings = new String[]{myString, myString1};
```