# Java split string with "||" taking it as regex instead of string

Tags: java

I have the following string `"ABC"` and `"AAA||BBB"`

I am trying to `split` it using the characters `"||"` but the `split` method is taking this as a regex expression, returning an array of characters instead of `{"ABC"}` and `{"AAA", "BBB"}`

I have tried scaping the bar with a back slash, but that didn't work.

How can I make the `split` method to take `"||"` as a String and not as a regex?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [String.split() \*not\* on regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374050/string-split-not-on-regular-expression)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape the pipes

Use `\\|\\|` instead

Comment: double back slash... that solved it! I was trying with only one. Thanks!

Comment: You need to escape the slash. This leads to a double slash.

Comment: just did. StackoverFlow has a time restriction to accept answers, I had to wait.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to deal with escaping then you can use `Pattern#quote`:

```
String[] tok = "AAA||BBB".split(Pattern.quote("||"));
```

OR simple:

```
String[] tok = "AAA||BBB".split("\\Q||\\E"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   String[] result = "The||man is very happy.".split("\\|\\|");

    for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++){

        System.out.print(result[x]);
     }
```

There you go its simple