# Java String Split on any character (including regex special characters)

Tags: java, string

I'm sure I'm just overlooking something here...

Is there a simple way to split a String on an explicit character without applying RegEx rules?

For instance, I receive a string with a dynamic delimiter, I know the 5th character defines the delimiter.

```
String s = "This,is,a,sample";
```

For this, it's simple to do

```
String delimiter = String.valueOf(s.charAt(4));
String[] result = s.split(delimiter);
```

However, when I have a delimiter that's a special RegEx character, this doesn't work:

```
String s = "This*is*a*sample";
```

So...  is there a way to split the string on an explicit character without trying to apply extra RegEx rules?  I feel like I must be missing something pretty simple.

Comment: Escape the regex character.

Comment: Use `Pattern.quote(delimiter)` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374050/string-split-not-on-regular-expression).

Comment: That's one of the reasons to prefer Guava's Splitter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) uses a regular expression as its argument. `*` is a meta-character used to match zero of more characters in regular expressions, You could use [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) to avoid interpreting the character

```
String[] result = s.split(Pattern.quote(delimiter));
```

Comment: Perfect, I knew there was something simple I was missing, just didn't know the right search term.  Thanks!

Comment: A note for people finding this answer in google:  be aware that the most common implementation of `split` explicitly checks for backslash+character delimiters that do not have special meaning in a regular expression, and runs a fast local loop instead of using the full `Pattern` engine.  By surrounding your character with `\Q...\E` (what `quote()` is doing), the delimiter will no longer trigger the fast path but instead create a new Pattern object on every call.  So, benchmark your code to see if this speed makes a difference, and if it does consider *carefully* escaping the character instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need not to worry about the character type If you use `Pattern`

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(s.charAt(4));
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(yourString);
if (matcher.find()){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run [Pattern.quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) on the delimiter before feeding it in.  This will create a string literal and escape any regex specific chars:

```
delimiter = Pattern.quote(delimiter);
```

Answer (score 0):

`StringUtils.split(s, delimiter);`

That will treat the delimiter as just a character, not use it like a regex.

`StringUtils` is a part of the `ApacheCommons` library, which is tons of useful methods. It is worth taking a look, could save you some time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your delimiter between []

```
String delimiter = "["+s.charAt(4)+"]";
String[] result = s.split(delimiter);
```

Since [ ] is the regex matches any characters between [ ]. You can also specify a list of delimiters like **[*,.+-]**