# How to split a java string at backslash

Tags: java

```
String fname="C:\textfiles\db\query\query.txt";
```

this is the string i need to split it.

I tried with this

```
String [] items=fname.split("\");
```

But not working.

```
String [] items=fname.split("\\"); also not working...
```

how to split this string...

Comment: Stop. Print out `fname` before you try anything else. You need to *escape the backslashes* in your string literal.

Comment: You must escape `"\"` when in quotes because it is a special character. You must escape `"\"` in regular expressions because it is a special character. The result is `"\\\\"`.
In any case use the Path object and you will get support for windows and Posix style of paths.

Answer (score 64):

First of all you can not have a string as you posted in question

```
String fname="C:\textfiles\db\query\query.txt";
```

this should be replaced by

```
String fname="C:\\textfiles\\db\\query\\query.txt";
```

as backslash("\") needs an escape as well.

Finally you need to do something like this to split them:

```
 String fname="C:\\textfiles\\db\\query\\query.txt";
 String[] items= fname.split("\\\\");
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 23):

'split' expects RegEx.
Best way to use split is using "Pattern.quote"

```
String separator = "\\";
String value = "C:\\Main\\text.txt";
String[] arrValues = value.split(Pattern.quote(separator));
```

Comment: Thist is the answer!

Answer (score 15):

it works.

```
String fname="C:\\textfiles\\db\\query\\query.txt";
       String split[]  = fname.split("\\\\");
       System.out.println(" :: value " + split[0] );
```

Comment: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.split(fname, "\\") does the job

Answer (score 9):

Please use the following code...

```
fname.split(Pattern.quote(File.separator));
```

Comment: Working in Windows and not working in Linux. Need to use "\\" to work with both OS

Answer (score 5):

First you need to replace all "\" occurrences with "\\" and then split using "\\".

```
String str="C:\Users\prajwal_nayak\Documents\queries.sql";
String separator = "\\";
String[] str_arr=str.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(separator), "\\\\").split("\\\\");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String[] splitPath (String path) {
    String backslash = ((char)92) + "";
    if (path.contains(backslash)) {
        ArrayList<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        for ( int c : path.toCharArray() ) {
            if (c == 92) {
                parts.add(path.substring(start, end));
                start = end + 1;
            }
            end++;
        }
        parts.add(path.substring(start));
        return parts.toArray( new String[parts.size()] );
    }
    return path.split("/");
}
```

Comment: An interesting approach to solving a problem that isn't the one asked here.

Comment: I think author asked why his usage of String.Split function doesn't work not for split algorithm implementation.

Comment: it's absolutely a solution for the above problem ("how to split this string..."). those answers that said you cannot have a string with a backslash are wrong. my example even shows how to create a string with a backslash. i was running into the problem on android and this is the quick solution that solves the split problem for me. the built in string.split() function will fail for those cases in a weird way (internal regex exception)

Answer (score 0):

```
**//single slash already used as space in java 
// suppose it would be Object Type obj="C:\textfiles\db\query\query.txt";**

public static void main(String[] args) {
String target="\\";
String replacement="\\\\";
String str=(String) obj;
str=str.replace(target, replacement);
String[] strarray=str.split(replacement);
String filename=strarray[8];
System.out.println("file Name: "+filename);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use the following code...

```
String str[]=fname.split("\\\\\\\");
```

Comment: \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\