# Java backslash split string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string in the format like "test\00216243".
I need to split the string in Java based on the backslash '\' .

```
My Program:

    public class StringTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String taskOwner = "test\00216243";
            String taskArray[] = taskOwner.split(Pattern.quote(System.getProperty("file.separator")));
            System.out.println(taskArray[0]);
        }
    }
```

When i run this program i am getting the following result but not the result as 'test'. Any help?

```
Result:
test16243
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\002` represents a unicode character. SO i suggest you to split your input according to the character other than alphabet or digit.

```
String string1 = "test\00216243";
String part[] = string1.split("[^a-z0-9]");
System.out.println(part[0]);
```

Output:

```
test
```

Comment: or `String part[] = string1.split("[^A-Za-z0-9]");`

Comment: `string1.split("[^a-z0-9]");` in this part you are looking for a character that is not in the set of [a-zA-Z0-9]. ^ implies NOT.

Comment: This method is good if you only going to split the string `"test\0216243"`. In future if you want to print this string as well then you need to use the below method. Give it a try printing it.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add on

`\` is a special character in regular expressions, as well as in Java string literals. If you want a literal backslash in a regex, you have to **double it twice.**

When you type `"\\"`, this is actually a single backslash (due to escaping special characters in Java Strings).

Regular expressions also use backslash as special character, and you need to escape it with another backslash. So in the end, you need to pass "\\" as pattern to match a single backslash.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String taskOwner = "test\\00216243";
        String taskArray[] = taskOwner.split("\\\\");
        System.out.println(taskArray[0]);
    }
```

**output**

```
test
00216243
```

Answer (score 0):

String `"test\00216243"` should be replaced with `"test\\00216243"`

Because `\` represent the escape sequence, you need to use `\\` in the string to represent a `\`

**Try this**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String taskOwner = "test\\00216243";
    String myarray[] = taskOwner.split("\\\\");
    System.out.println(myarray[0]+"   "+myarray[1]);

}
```

**Output**

```
test   00216243
```

**Reference:**

[How to split a java string at backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751618/how-to-split-a-java-string-at-backslash)

Comment: Shouldn't `split("\\\\")` be `split("\\")`?

Comment: op tells that `"test\00216243"` is an exact input. Why you change the input? `\002` represents an ascii character..

Comment: @StephenB No. It shouldn't be `split("\\")` because `test\\00216243` has 2 backslash so 2 for each or them. Hence `split("\\\\")`

Comment: @AvinashRaj When your input has an escape sequence in it, you have to handle that before processing it. So changing the the input is necessary here.