# how to split string based on delimiter as "\"

Tags: java, string

I am trying to split the below String based on backslash"\" but unable to achieve this for `mar\12\2013`

```
String s1 = "mar\12\2013";
String[] s =s1.split("\\\\");
for(String s2 : s){
    System.out.println(s2);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to define the `String` as `mar\\12\\2013` before it will work, but otherwise your code works fine for me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a java string at backslash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751618/how-to-split-a-java-string-at-backslash)

Comment: the internal representation of your string is `mar\n3` So there is no backslash in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java `"mar\12\2013"` is an invalid string.

To use `mar\12\2013` in Java, you need `"mar\\12\\2013"`.

If you are taking input from user as `"mar\12\2013"`, then also you have to split it with `\\\\`.

**Reason :** **[`.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))** takes **[`regex`](http://www.digitalamit.com/article/regular_expression/2.phtml)** as a parameter.

- To specify `\` in regex, we need `\\`, because `\` is an escape character in `regex`.
- Also, `\` is an escape character in Java, so we need to escape both `\` of `\\`, which makes it `\\\\`.

  ```
  String s1= //take input from user                 // "mar\12\2013"
  String[]s=s1.split("\\\\");
  for(String s2:s) {
      System.out.println(s2);
  }
  ```

The above code will work the way you wish.

See the working code [**here**](http://ideone.com/R9RJ3q).

Comment: actually  i am getting data in my program  with single backslash "\" only.so how can i split that one. please help.

Comment: by using  s1.split("\\\\") it's not  splitting correctly.

Comment: mar
?3
this output i m getting

Comment: it's working fine if i am taking  string as user input  and reading through readLine() method. but not working when i m directly supplying that string.

Comment: Then where is the problem now?

Comment: see in my program i m supplying string value directly like this   Strings1="mar\12\2013";               
        String[]s=s1.split("\\\\");
        for(String s2:s) {
            System.out.println(s2);
        }                                            then only i m getting problem.

Comment: `String s1="mar\12\2013";` this will **NOT** even compile, because `"mar\12\2013"` is an illegal string value in Java. If you are assigning value directly, do like this. `String s1="mar\\12\\2013";`

Comment: thank you . my problem is solved.i am getting data like "mar\\12\\2013".

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1="mar\12\2013";
String[]s=s1.split("\\");
for(String s2:s){
    System.out.println(s2);
}
```

You doubled up the selectors, i cant actually test atm but i believe it just needs the 2, the first escaping the second.

Answer (score 0):

See the below code it worked fine for me

```
public class StringTest {

        public static void main(String arg[]){
         String s1="mar\\12\\2013";
            String[]s=s1.split("\\");
            for(String s2:s){

                System.out.println(s2);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it works fine for  if two backslashes are present. but my  string containing single backslash only.

Comment: @Shrinivas Shukla already mentioned what the issue and how you can solve it