# Split by backslash in javascript

Tags: javascript, backslash

I'm trying to split a string `"\b1\c1\d1"` into `["","b1","c1","d1"]`;

But even with `string.split("\\")` (and all ways that internet says) it simply give me a `["1c1d1"]`;

How can I get the result I want?

Comment: \ denotes an escape sequence.  What _precisely_ do your strings contain?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751618/how-to-split-a-java-string-at-backslash

Comment: `\b` is treated as a special character (backspace).

Comment: \b \c \d are a parameter on my string, and 1 its value, i'm trying to separe they into a array as ["b1","c1","d1"]. But split simply don't work :/
Replace "\" with other chars don't work too.

Comment: How are you testing your code?  Where is the initial string coming from - are you hard coding it as `var x = "\b1\c1\d1"` or are you receiving it from somewhere etc

Comment: I'm reading from a file :/ so i can't replace the backslash on the source

Comment: That's fine - but how is the string being brought from the file into your code - you need to add all these details as it's not clear how your string is being constructed and whether or not the slashes should be escaped.

Comment: Sorry if i not understanded your question again, my english isn't so good.
But if a understanded right:

The \b \c \d are pure examples :D
I'm reading from file a string such "\parametervalue\parametervalue", my intial logic was split into a array ['parametervalue','parametervalue'] to next identify the parameters and get the value...

Comment: Then you oversimplified it, removing details necessary to understand your scenario. Please update your question with the real requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me this way.

Tested on chrome console:

```
var x = "\b1\c1\d1"; // results in "1c1d1"
var x = "\\b1\\c1\\d1"; // results in "b1\c1\d1"
var y = x.split("\");
VM160:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token     ILLEGAL(…)InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM101:875InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM101:808InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM101:664
var y = x.split("\\");  // THIS WORKS!! ["", "b1", "c1", "d1"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The most easier way of doing is by converting the given string in raw string where we retrieve the backslash as it is

for above scenario `"\b1\c1\d1"` into `["","b1","c1","d1"]`

```
let a = String.raw`YOUR_STRING`;

let b=a.split("\\");

for eg;

let a =String.raw`\b1\c1\d1`; //Output a ="\b1\c1\d1"

let b = a.split("\\"); // Output b = ["", "b1", "c1", "d1"]
```

Have already tested in chrome console and for more information on String.raw method please refer: [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw)

Answer (score 0):

You can split your "fictional string" if it will be a regexp object

```
/\b1\c1\d1/.source.split('\\');
```