# String returned by 'path' module having multiple backslash, processing in JS

Tags: javascript, string

I am facing the very old problem i n javacript. Using the npm 'path' module i have read the directory of a js file. and the directory can be found using **path.resolve(__dirname)**. The directory varies based on os.

```
linux and mac os: /projectname/componentname/foldername
windows: projectname\componentname\foldername
```

I want to count the number of word in the directory.

in linux & mac os i can easily split it based on '/'. but in windows i can not split in based on '\'. i think its because on the scape character. How can i successfully split the string based on '\' and count the words successfully.

**NB**: for the two string the string length varies. so in the windows environment the path.resolve(__dirname) the actual directory name is not the one i desire. some of the characters is lost due to scape.

```js
var x = 'projectname\component\foldername\form';
alert(x.split("\\"));
```

How can i convert the string 'projectname\component\foldername\form' into 'projectname\component\foldername\form'. cause in 'projectname\component\foldername\form' some characters are missing due to the backslash and treated as scape sequence.

Comment: in javascript you need to use `\\` to split instead og `\`

Comment: Am I the only one who finds this question very basic and a simple google could resolve this issue?? I do not understand how some people just upvote randomly?

Comment: "i think its because on the scape character" — Maybe. How should we know though? You haven't included a [MCVE]

Comment: `split("\\")` seems to work just fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split by backslash in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213673/split-by-backslash-in-javascript)

Comment: I have added a code snippet. Probably it will make the question more clear now.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal i have made the question more clear now.  splitting using '\\' is not working. a code snippet is added. hope it makes sense.

Comment: alert will not work.. you'll have to put it like `alert(x.split('\\')[0])`

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal the string should be converted to 'projectname\\component\\foldername\\form' from 'projectname\component\foldername\form' to get the desired output.

Comment: No My friend, the first slash is escaped as that is an escape character and the second  one is considered as the character (in general string) to split upon.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal so why there is some characters missing after those '\' ??? have a look at the output of the snippet.

Comment: That is because if you missed the concept of escape charater altogether. Yes the string has to have double slashes and when you read from windows, it gives you the exact readable string. If you log `__dirname` you'd know that.

Answer (score 1):

path.resolve(__dirname).split(/[\\/]/);

this should solve both cases

Comment: working for forword slash but not for backslash. for back slash i am getting output projectnamecomponentoldernameorm. here you can see some of the characters are missing. those who are after the backslash.

Comment: @RefatRafi the problem is not about splitting but about your sample path - it should be `var x = 'projectname\\component\\foldername\\form';`

Comment: @Adassko path.resolves(__dirname) returns 'projectname\component\foldername\form'. have to add '\\' in place of '\'. any tips to do that???

Comment: @RefatRafi if it returns `'projectname\component\foldername\form'` then it's ok and you don't need to add anything - you can split this value using your own code. Double backspaces are only needed when you provide values manually from code