# How do I split a string by "\\"

Tags: java, regex, string, split, filepath

```
        String s = "E:\Confluence_Attachments\ver003\10\85\"
            + "1835010\124\165\4915874\19169322\1";
```

How do I split the above string by "\". I tries the following two methods and both did not work.

Method1:

```
        String pattern = Pattern.quote(System.getProperty("file.separator"));
        String[] splittedFileName = s.split(pattern);

        System.out.println(" extractReqFields:  ");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splittedFileName));
```

Method2:

```
        //String pattern2 = "\\";
        //String[] splittedFileName2 = s.split(pattern);
        String[] splittedFileName2 = s.split("\\");

        System.out.println(" extractReqFields2222:  ");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splittedFileName2));
```

I am getting the following string from an another method:

```
 String s = "E:\Confluence_Attachments\ver003\10\85\"
            + "1835010\124\165\4915874\19169322\1";
```

So I can't escape the backslash. Now how would I split it by '\'?

Should I add an escape character programmatically using regex and then split?

Can you tell me how do I add the escape character programmatically?

I can understand there's an answer here:

[How to split a java string at backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751618/how-to-split-a-java-string-at-backslash)

But my question is how do i add the escape character programatically. I need help with that.

Comment: You're hitting a special feature of `String.split`. It doesn't simply take a string, but a regular expression! And the regex `"\\"` (one backslash) simply doesn't match anything. You have to escape the backslash (with another one) as the other answers suggest.

Comment: I don’t understand your edit, sorry. To split the string you get at backslash, you don’t need to escape the backslashes in the string. Only the backslashes in the regular expression you use for splitting. The two answers both work. Another comment is you may look into the `Path` class for representing your path name rather than just splitting it into an array.

Comment: Also your method 1 works for me and gives `[E:, Confluence_Attachments, ver003, 10, 85, 1835010, 124, 165, 4915874, 19169322, 1]` (didn’t test on Windows, so no guarantee, but I believe).

Answer (score 5):

Just use `"\\\\"`. Java interprets `"\\"` as one `"\"`, so `"\\\\"` = `"\\"`

```
String s = "E:\\Confluence_Attachments\\ver003\\10\\85\\"
        + "1835010\\124\\165\\4915874\\19169322\\1";

String[] splittedFileName2 = s.split("\\\\");

System.out.println(" extractReqFields2222:  ");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splittedFileName2));
```

Output:

> ```
>  extractReqFields2222:  
> [E:, Confluence_Attachments, ver003, 10, 85, 1835010, 124, 165, 4915874, 19169322, 1]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 String s = "E:\\Confluence_Attachments\\ver003\\10\\85\\"
                + "1835010\\124\\165\\4915874\\19169322\\1";
       String[] splittedFileName2 = s.split("\\\\");

       System.out.println(" extractReqFields2222:  ");

       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splittedFileName2));
```

O/P

```
extractReqFields2222:  
[E:, Confluence_Attachments, ver003, 10, 85, 1835010, 124, 165, 4915874, 19169322, 1]
```