# I want to split the string

Tags: java

I want to split the following String
`"C:\ATS\Script\SampleFiles\xml\books.xml"`
to extract only name of the file (`books.xml`)

I tried using the split function but couldn't split `\`

```
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
       String fol = file.getCanonicalPath() ;
       String foln = fol.split("C:\\ATS\\Script\\SampleFiles\\xml")[1];         
       System.out.println("directory:" + foln);
    }
```

I want the output to extract only the file name
i.e books.xml

Comment: first of all, why can't you split? secondly: your split argument makes no sense. try passing "\\" instead of the entire String

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751618/how-to-split-a-java-string-at-backslash

Comment: Try String foln = fol.split("\")[5];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a java string at backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751618/how-to-split-a-java-string-at-backslash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getFileName()` method in [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName())

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/ATS/Script/SampleFiles/xml/books.xml");
System.out.println(path.getFileName().toString());
```

Output

```
books.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this it?

```
String fol = ...
String split[];

split = fol.split("\\");

String foln = split[split.length-1];
```

Comment: Not all the separators in different OS are backslashes.

Comment: I think the better way is to use `File.separator`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simpler

```java
File dir = new File("D:\\foo");
File file = new File("D:\\foo\\test.txt");

System.out.println("file.getName() = " + file.getName()); // test.txt
System.out.println("dir.getName() = " + dir.getName()); // foo
```