# Set of Characters as Delimiter in string tokenizer JAVA

Tags: java, string, split

How to split the text in to sentence based on set of characters as delimiter ?.
I have a function where user will input text and the delimiter. Delimiter can be single character or a string (user can specify 'xyz' as a delimiter). 
I have tried 
 `StringTokenizer(text, delimiter)`  which takes only character as delimiter. Next option was 
 `String.split()`  but this fails when I give delimiter such as '**'. It requires "\" to be appended to the delimiter.
Appending "\" looks like very tedious job because if the delimiter is "**" then I have to change it to "\*\*". If the delimiter is say "< TAB >" then I split function looks like `String [] sentences = text.split("\\<TAB\\>");`

Is there any easy way to split text in to sentences based of set of characters as delimiter ?.

Comment: `StringTokenizer(String, String)` doesn't only accept a single character as a delimiter, it accepts a `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could easily google this, yet I will provide you the answer:

```
String separator = ...
s.split(Pattern.quote(separator));
```

The answer comes directly from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6374137/4907382).