# Escape special symbols from regexpr

Tags: java, regex

I use this code:

```
static Pattern escaper = Pattern.compile("([^a-zA-z0-9])");

public static String escapeRE(String str) {
    return escaper.matcher(str).replaceAll("\\\\$1");
}
```

It works pretty, until I don't use this string: "[". I looked in the debuger  the result is "]" without "\\".

```
System.out.println(Main.escapeRE("+"));
System.out.println(Main.escapeRE(">="));
System.out.println(Main.escapeRE("]"));
System.out.println(Main.escapeRE("["));
```

Result:

```
\\+
\\>\\=
]
[
```

Why it is so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape text for regular expression in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java) - It looks like you're trying to implement `Pattern#quote()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your character class `[^a-zA-z0-9]` is incorrect. It should be: `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` (note the `A-Z` instead of `A-z`).

Since both `[` and `]` are included in the range `A-z`, they're not replaced by your `escapeRE` method.

### EDIT

As @Matt mentioned in the comments: if you're trying to escape regex-meta-chars, have a look at the [Pattern.quote(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) method which is created especially for this purpose.