# Java - Escaping Meta-characters [ and ] in Regex

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I am attempting to replace the first occurrence of the string "[]" in another string:

aString.replaceFirst("[]", "blah");

I get the error: 
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 1 []

[ and ] are obviously metacharacters, however when I try to escape them with a \ 
eclipse complains that it is not a valid escape sequence.

I've looked but couldn't find, what am I missing?

Thank You

Comment: How about using the [Pattern.quote](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) method? (As shown in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java))

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. Pattern.quote() produces a string which eclipse would not accept (using \Q and \E), but it is a valid workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regex patterns use `\` as escape character, but so does Java. So to get a *single* escape (`\`) in a regex pattern you should write: `\\`. To escape an escape inside a regex, double the pattern: `\\\\`.

Of course that's extremely tedious, made all the worse because regexes have a ton of escape sequences like that. Which is why Java regexes also support “quoting” litteral parts of the pattern and this allows you to write your pattern as: `\\Q[]\\E`.

EDIT: As the other answer hints at: `java.util.regex.Pattern.quote()` performs this wrapping between `\\Q` and `\\E`.

Comment: This worked. I tried \Q and \E but not with double backslashes. Thanks. Accepting as answer in 3min

Answer (score 4):

Try \\[ and \\]. You need to double escape, because \ is also an escape character for strings (as is \" when you want to have double-quotes in your text). Therefore to get a \ in your string you have to use \\.

Comment: That didn't throw an error, however it did not actually replace [] and work as intended. I don't know why it failed. Using Pattern.quote() worked however.

Answer (score 2):

```
aString.replaceFirst("\\[\\]", "blah");
```

or in the more general case

```
aString.replaceFirst(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote("[]"), "blah");
```