# Java regular expression interpretation

Tags: java, regex

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Splitter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[,\\s]+");
        String[] results = p.split("one,two, three   four ,  five");
        for (String result : results) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

The splitter is either a comma or a whitespace or a combination of any number of them. I thought the regular expression for it should be `[,\s]+`. Why was there an extra backslash in the example?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.  Post text instead.

Comment: You could use a StringTokenizer instead.

Comment: What kind of asking a question is that? Do you want to prevent possible helpers to cut and paste your code to test/improve it?

Comment: @Vipar StringTokenizer has actually be deprecated in favour of split.

Comment: Really? Interesting. I didn't know this.

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/a/7904762/1330481

Comment: @dann.dev are you sure? The docs have no mention of it even for Java7 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: @Chip interesting, it seems it 'was' deprecated, see this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983856/why-is-stringtokenizer-deprecated

Comment: @Vipar see the above link, seems I'm wrong and it's not deprecated anymore

Comment: @dann.dev You are **NOT** wrong :) Looking at the javadoc again, the part about the **legacy code** is buried deep inside it. It's strange that they did not mark it as deprecated like they normally do. Sorry for the confusion, I did not know that line was there. So final word - it is not formally deprecated, but the use is **discouraged**.

Comment: @Chip if memory serves me (and sometimes it doesn't) i have a feeling when it first became legacy, eclipse would suggest that is was deprecated, which may be where the confusion arose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extra `\` is to escape the next backslash. In any Java string `"\\"` means `"\"`.

This is because the `'\'` is a special character. You must have seen `"\n"` used to mean newline right? So to put a literal `\` in a string you use `"\\"`.

For example try `System.out.println("Here\'s a backslash : \\")`.

This will print :
`Here's a backslash : \`

Comment: Why is the first backslash gone in the output?

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng `\'` means the character `'`. The character `'` is not required to be escaped in  a string but `\'` means `'`. Try it out.