# String.endsWith() not working

Tags: java, string, ends-with

I have the following string

```
http://store.aqa.org.uk/qual/newgcse/pdf/AQA-4695-W-SP.PDF
```

I want it so if the user forgets to input the http:// or the .PDF, the program will automatically correct this. Therefore, I tried this code

```
if (!str.startsWith("http://")) { // correct forgetting to add 'http://'
        str = "http://" + str;
    }
    System.out.println(str);
    if (!str.endsWith("\\Q.PDF\\E")) {
        str = str + "\\Q.pdf\\E";
    }
```

However, even when I enter the correct string, `http://store.aqa.org.uk/qual/newgcse/pdf/AQA-4695-W-SP.PDF`
the output is this.

```
http://store.aqa.org.uk/qual/newgcse/pdf/AQA-4695-W-SP.PDF\Q.pdf\E
```

Why? Why is **another** '.PDF' being added?

Comment: It's not clear why you think `endsWith` isn't working. Why would you expect it to return `true` in this case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because `http://store.aqa.org.uk/qual/newgcse/pdf/AQA-4695-W-SP.PDF` doesn't have a `\Q.PDF\E` on the end. In a string literal, `\\` gives you a backslash. So `"\\Q.PDF\\E"` is `\Q.PDF\E` — a backslash, followed by a `Q`, followed by a dot, followed by `PDF`, followed by another backslash, followed by `E`.

If you want to see if the string ends with `.PDF`, just use

```
if (!str.endsWith(".PDF"))
```

Of course, that's case-sensitive. If you want it to be case-insensitive, probably:

```
if (!str.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"))
```

Comment: But it has the .PDF which is what I am testing for?

Comment: @NightStrider: No, you're not testing for ".PDF" - you're testing for backslash Q dot PDF backslash E. The code is behaving exactly as I'd expect - what isn't clear is why you'd expect it to behave any other way.

Comment: I was looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904695/java-escaping-meta-characters-and-in-regex

Comment: That saud to wrap what I wanted in \\Q &\\E

Answer (score 3):

Hy. I  think this is what you want:

```
    String str = "http://store.aqa.org.uk/qual/newgcse/pdf/AQA-4695-W-SP";
    //String str = "http://store.aqa.org.uk/qual/newgcse/pdf/AQA-4695-W-SP.PDF";
    if (!str.startsWith("http://")) { // correct forgetting to add 'http://'
        str = "http://" + str;
    }
    System.out.println(str);
    if (!str.endsWith(".PDF")) {
        str = str + ".PDF";
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**-** Its simply because your String `http://store.aqa.org.uk/qual/newgcse/pdf/AQA-4695-W-SP.PDF` **doesNot** ends with `\Q.PDF\E`

**-** If you are concerned with matching the .PDF, then do this...

```
if (s.endsWith(".PDF")){

  // add it at the end....

}
```

**-** It would be more appropriate to use `StringBuilder` here instead of `String`, which is **mutable**.