# Find first occurrence of any symbol of string in other string

Tags: java, string, matching

I have a problem: I need to find first occurrence of *any symbol* from string **s2** (or array of char) in string **s1**.

Is there standard function for this purpose? If there isn't, whats the good implementation for this problem? (Of course I can run *indexOf* for every char from my s2, but this does't seem like a good algorithm, because if only the last symbol occurs in **s1**, we must run through **s1** *|s2|-1* times before I get an answer).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Nope; the Java String class has nothing like this.  Can you imagine a better algorithm than the one you describe?

Comment: I would pack the character of string s2 into a [regular expression](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) e.g. 'a|b|c|d' (special characters must be escaped) and then use Matcher.find(..) to get the first occurrence.

Comment: @maerics I doubt it's faster. Using a regular expression like that you only need to iterate once through the string.

Comment: Although you could also just iterate through it manually checking if each character is in the array of char (s2) which would be even faster. He'll have to be doing this millions of times though for any of these to be noticably different.

Comment: I've posted a simplistic functioning answer which shows how it might be done using regex as @AndreHolzner suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put all characters from `s2` into a constant-time lookup data structure (e.g. [`HashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)).  Iterate over each character in `s1` and see if your data structure contains that character.

Roughly (untested):

```
public int indexOfFirstContainedCharacter(String s1, String s2) {
  Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
  for (int i=0; i<s2.length; i++) {
    set.add(s2.charAt(i)); // Build a constant-time lookup table.
  }
  for (int i=0; i<s1.length; i++) {
    if (set.contains(s1.charAt(i)) {
      return i; // Found a character in s1 also in s2.
    }
  }
  return -1; // No matches.
}
```

This algorithm is `O(n)` as opposed to `O(n^2)` in the algorithm you describe.

Answer (score 4):

Using regex:

```
   public static void main(final String[] args) {
      final String s1 = "Hello World";
      final String s2 = "log";

      final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[" + Pattern.quote(s2) + "]");
      final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);
      if (matcher.find()) {
         System.out.println(matcher.group());
      }
   }
```

Comment: you should escape special characters before compiling the pattern, e.g. using `Pattern.quote(..)`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java

Comment: Yeah, this answer probably needs a fair amount of beefing up to be robust. A string that contains a hyphen would also cause some issues I think.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is [`indexOfAny`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#indexOfAny%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20char...%29) from Apache StringUtils.

It looks like the implementation is:

```
 public static int indexOfAny(String str, char[] searchChars) {
   if (isEmpty(str) || ArrayUtils.isEmpty(searchChars)) {
     return -1;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
     char ch = str.charAt(i);
       for (int j = 0; j < searchChars.length; j++) {
         if (searchChars[j] == ch) {
           return i;
         }
       }
     }
    return -1;
  }
```

Comment: Linear search? Ow, better make sure that `searchChars` is never large. I thought Apache would do something a bit more sophisticated.

Answer (score 3):

What is meant by *symbol* in this context? If it's just a 16-bit Java `char`, it's easy. Make a lookup table (array) for all possible values, indicating whether they appear in s2. Then step through s1 until either you've found a symbol from s2 or you've reached the end of s1. If a *symbol* is a Unicode code-point, it's more complicated, but the above gives a method to find out where you need to take a closer look.

Comment: you mean, you would initialize an array of 2^16 booleans where only the elements corresponding to an character in s2 are set to true ? (interesting idea; I think a HashSet could perform nearly as well)

Comment: @AndreHolzner Yes, that's the idea. 2^16 is small enough, so there's no need to use fancy stuff like HashSets, the simple array will do. I'm not familiar enough with the JVM, but in C I would be quite confident that it's also faster, because it fits comfortably in L2 (given normal hardware). Were `char`s 20 bits or more, the array would become too big, so then definitely some kind of set.