# How to Split ( " ) Using Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm new in Java
I have a string which is get by `StringBuilder` from a HTML file, and I had split it numerous step, and now I put it into a String, lets called it **alink**

`aLink` is a `String` which contain `<a href="http//www.google.com">Google</a>`

I want to use method `.split(String regex)` in Java, so that I can get **http://www.google.com** and put it into a String variable.

My question is, how to do it, because i cannot put **"** into my parameter.

Thank you

Comment: put an example aLink. You can escape special chars in Java like \\"

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java

Comment: Why don't you use a `Pattern` and a `Matcher` to get the URL instead of using split?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use \ to escape special characters:

```
string.split("\"");
```