# Quote/Escape path for use in regex

Tags: java, regex, scala

Considering a path such as

> var dir = new File("""c:\test\project1""");

How do I easily in Scala escape/quote this so it can be used safely in regular expressions

> val extractRelativePath = (dir.getAbsolutePath() + """(.*)""").r

I tried using

> dir.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");

but this does not work. as the following example shows

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  var base = new File("""c:\test\project1""");
  val extractRelativePath = (base.getAbsolutePath() + """(.*)""").r

  var dir = new File("""c:\test\project1\somedir""");
  var extractRelativePath(rel) = dir.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\")
}
```

Also is there not some standard functionality that does this safely across platforms like **Pattern.quote** ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [quotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quot), but I think that in your case you also need to escape `\E`. Following code should do it:

```
("""\Q""" + base.getAbsolutePath.replaceAll("\\\\E", "\\\\E\\\\\\\\E\\\\Q") + """\E(.*)""").r
```

I generally replacing `\E` with `\E\\E\Q`, so I split quotation and explicitly adding `\\` followed by `E` in regexp.

Here is small example. If I have defined `base` like his:

```
var base = new File("""c:\test\Earth""");
```

then it will produce following regexp:

```
\Qc:\test\E\\E\Qarth\E(.*)
```

As an advantage to this approach, `\Q` and `\E` will escape everything and not only `*` or `\`.

---

Here is the whole example code:

```
var base = new File("""c:\test\Earth""");
val extractRelativePath = ("""\Q""" + base.getAbsolutePath.replaceAll("\\\\E", "\\\\E\\\\\\\\E\\\\Q") + """\E(.*)""").r

var dir = new File("""c:\test\Earth\somedir""");
var extractRelativePath(rel) = dir.getAbsolutePath

println(rel) // prints: \somedir
```

---

#### By the way

You can also use `Pattern.quote` which makes exactly the same, but more efficiently:

```
(Pattern.quote(base.getAbsolutePath) + """(.*)""").r
```

Comment: utterly amazing, I was not even close with my own attempts

Answer (score 1):

Looks funny, but it should at least escape the backslashes.

```
replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\")
```

But what you should use is Pattern.quote. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java).

Comment: This causes my regex to fail with "java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown character property name {r} near index 9 c:\test\project1(.*)"

Comment: no idea what is going on there unless you post the code that is causing this error.

Comment: added a minimal runnable example