# Cleaning text for regex

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to escape text for regular expression in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java)

Is there a built in way or a standard library for cleaning arbitrary strings for use in regex?

As in, if I have the string `something .* foo` and I want to turn that into a regex like `^something \.\* foo$` is that something that can be easily done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Pattern.quote(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) for this purpose. From the docs:

> Returns a literal pattern `String` for the specified `String`.
>
> This method produces a `String` that can be used to create a `Pattern` that would
>   match the string `s` as if it were a literal pattern.
>
> Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given
>   no special meaning.

Comment: Great, thank you. I'll accept your answer when I am able to.