# adding variables in a regular expression to make it dynamic in java

Tags: java, regex, dynamic

I need to form a regular expression in order to check the outputs of a response log. The log file will always be different based on the input. Thus, I want to create a *dynamic* regular expression based on the input to the function.
I may need to pass variable number of variables at a time for comparison, so how can that 'or' factor be inserted in the regex?

Is it possible to create such a regular expression in Java, and how should I go about it?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just use string concatenation, though you'll probably want to escape the variable parts to be safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the regex is only a string, you can concatenate your user input to constant parts and then create a pattern from it.

If you want to match the user input literally, you should use `Pattern.quote("UserString")` to [regex escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java) it.

**Example:**

```
String UserInput = "Bar()";
String Prefix = "Foo";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Prefix + Pattern.quote(UserInput));

String s1 = "FooBar()";
String s2 = "FooBarNo";

String[] s = { s1, s2};

for (String a : s) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(a);
    if (m.find())
        System.out.println(a + " ==> Success");
    else
        System.out.println(a + " ==> Failure");
}
```

**Output:**

> FooBar() ==> Success
>   FooBarNo ==> Failure

Comment: thanks for the reply, that was pretty easy stuff, but the main problem for me is that it is not necessary that each time I need to add the same number of variables ... sometimes it may be 4 and sometimes 6 or more ...
what to do in that case ?

Comment: @ashfaq then you're going to have to edit your question to be more specific, because we're not mind readers.

Comment: Thanks MДΓΓ БДLL, @ashfaq What about a loop where you add all the strings you want?

Comment: @stema thanks for the snippet, very near to my need... i'll build upon it.:-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that by concatenating. e.g: "your regex" + "{" + input + "}".