# replace substring in string when string contains [] characters

Tags: java

I want to replace substringin string.
For example:

```
localStringBuilder is for example "[sender] is xxxx xxxx xxx".
```

and when I run

```
localStringBuilder.toString().replaceAll("[sender]", callerName);
```

not working correctly. Prblem is with `[]` characters. How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `replace` in place of `replaceAll`

`replaceAll` take REGEX as input, not a String, but regex. `[]` are important parts of regexes using to group expressions.

`localStringBuilder.toString().replace("[sender]", callerName);` will work exaclty as you expect, because it takes normal Strings as both parameters.

`is the same. Works when is no [] characters in string` – @mbrc 1 min ago

not true, I've **tested** it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "asd[something]123";
    String replace = s.replace("[something]", "new1");
    System.out.println(replace);
}
```

**output: asdnew1123**

Comment: is the same.  Works when is no [] characters in string

Comment: @mbrc, no problem. I have to say that it's kind of sad, that among all those answers only mine suggested using `replace` here. Your problem wasn't wrong way of using regex, but JUST using it, when you probably didn't want to :) Adding `\\` wouldn't make your code better, it would just a hack to solve issue that shouldn't occur in the first place

Answer (score 0):

replaceAll returns a new string with the replacement. It doesn't replace the characters in the original string.

> String newString = localStringBuilder.toString().replaceAll("[sender]", callerName);

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
   localStringBuilder.toString().replaceAll("\\[sender\\]", callerName);
```

Comment: what if [sender] is constant and i can not use \\?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java

Comment: Or your could just use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char, char) like another person mentioned

Answer (score 0):

**This works:**

```
locaStringBuilder.toString().replaceAll("\\[sender\\]", callerName);
```