# How to split a string like p^q using split function in Java?

Tags: java, regex, split, escaping

I want to split a string like "p^q" into two strings, i.e. "p" and "q". How can I do this using "string.split" in Java. I have used syntaxes like `s.split("^")`, `s.split("\^")`, and `s.split("\\^")` ! But the arraylist always has one element! Thanks

Comment: I remember the same question being asked yesterday or two days before.  Do a search.

Comment: What ArrayList? `split()` returns a `String[]` not an `ArrayList`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape text for regular expression in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("p^q".split("\\^")));
```

prints

```
[p, q]
```

which proves that the array returned by `split` has not one, but two elements, and exactly those that you require.

Comment: Note that his last trial was `"\\^"` (though it was displayed wrongly due to lack of code block)

Comment: @amit In that case, the `Arrays.toString` part should be of help.