# Treat string for regex use

Tags: java, regex

I've got my own `indexOf` function

```
private static int indexOf(String target, String pattern){

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(target);

    if(matcher.find()){

        return matcher.start();

    }

    return -1;
}
```

This function takes in a user provided `pattern` and to see if the `pattern` exists within the `target` String. Sometimes a user could include regex characters like `*** hello world` in the String and this causes the function to return a `Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*'` error.

How can I treat the user generated String to overcome errors like these?

Comment: Are they supposed to be able to include regex characters used *properly*?

Comment: @ExplosionPills They are not.. I want the regex char's to be treated the same as `s` `a` `b` etc.

Comment: "I've got my own indexOf function."  Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String))

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern));
```

Note: this assumes that it isn't a real regex being passed in.

> public static String quote(String s)
>
> Returns a literal pattern String for the specified String. This method
> produces a String that can be used to create a Pattern that would
> match the string s as if it were a literal pattern.
>
> Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given
> no special meaning.