# How to sanitize a String for regexp

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a `java.lang.String` that may contain any character possible, is there a easy way to sanitize the string (for example with an additional class that can do that?) and remove all "dangerous" characters for a later `java.util.regex.Matcher` or regex processing (e.g. $, ^, ...)?

Comment: Too complicated to do it, consider using your string as argument of Pattern.match(string) instead of parsing your string

Comment: Would quoting them also be ok? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use

```
Pattern.quote(string);
```

to escape your string for Regex.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `\Q..\E`escape sequence.

Here is an example for [Metacharacters Inside Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Any thing inside `\Q..\E` pair is considered as literal.

Comment: There's a risk of `\E` being part of the string, which will terminate the escape sequence. You're safe using hsz's answer.