# Java use replaceAll with Escape Characters String

Tags: java, xml, regex, string

Good night Stack Overflow!

Tonight I'm trying to remove the "header" from an XML I've parsed as a string and use replaceAll to remove the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

From the string. Since it's going to be concatenated with another XML String, and leaving it would leave two of those.

So I tried:

```
// getXML already has my XML.
getXML = getXML.replaceAll("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>", "");
```

This fails to compile, due to the "" inside of the String. I then tried with escape sequences:

```
String headerXMLString = ("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>");
getXML = getXML.replaceAll(headerXMLString, "");
```

This fails as well, While the program itself runs I assume due to the escapes (\) it doesn't delete the string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

Since the String is technically not the same.

How would one work around this? Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `replaceAll()`, which does a *regex* search.
Instead use `replace()`, which uses *plain-text* search.

```
getXML = getXML.replace(headerXMLString, "");
```

Note that despite the unfortunate name difference, `replace()` still replaces *all* occurrences found.

---

A better approach would be to use regex to match the XML header no matter what it contains:

```
getXML = getXML("^<?xml.*?\\?>", "");
```

This would also do nothing if there was no header.

Comment: @Erick i posted the same answer long back :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use `replace()` instead `replaceAll()` following works for me

```
String s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>";
String s2 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>";
s2 = s2.replace(s, "");
System.out.println(s2);
```

**OP:**

```
<blank>
```

EDIT:

how about following?

```
String s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("D:\\temp.txt"));
String s2 = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("b4 "+s2);
s2 = s2.replaceAll(s, "");
System.out.println("aftr "+s2);
```

File Content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

Comment: This is not applicable in my case because the String that has the line doesn't have escape sequences. You are deleting identical strings.

Comment: i told you the same thing :) did not i??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a literal pattern either use [`Pattern.Quote` or `\Q ... \E`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
Pattern.quote("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>")
```

**http://regex101.com/r/cF3aI1**

Working Java example showing both methods:

**https://ideone.com/mZwwOs**

Comment: Attempting to use: getXML = getXML.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>"), "");  leads to a compile error. How would I get around that?

Comment: You'll still need to escape the quotes.