# Escape each literal in regex string instead of quote the entire string

Tags: java, regex, string, escaping

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java) suggesting to use `Pattern.quote` in order to escape the special regex characters.

The problem with `Pattern.quote` is it escapes the string as a whole, not each of the special character on its own.

This is my case:
I receive a string from the user, and need to search for it in a document.
Since the user can't pass new line characters (It's a bug in a 3rd party API I have no access to), I decieded to treat any whitespace sequence as "\s+" and use a regex to search the document. This way the user can send a simple whitespace instead of a newline character.

For instance, if the document is:

> The \s metacharacter is used to find a whitespace character.
>
> A whitespace character can be:
>
> A space character
>
> A tab character
>
> A carriage return character
>
> A new line character
>
> A vertical tab character
>
> A form feed character

Then the received string

```
String receivedStr = "The \s metacharacter is used to find a whitespace character. A whitespace character can be:";
```

should be found in the document.

To acheive this I want to quote the string, and then replace any whitespace sequence with the string "\s+".
Using the following code:

```
receivedStr = Pattern.quote(receivedStr).replaceAll("\\s+", "\\\\s+");
```

yield the regex:

> \QThe\s+\s\s+metacharacter\s+is\s+used\s+to\s+find\s+a\s+whitespace\s+character.\s+A\s+whitespace\s+character\s+can\s+be:\E

that will ofcourse ignore my added `"\s+"`'s instead of the expected:

> The\s+\\s\s+metacharacter\s+is\s+used\s+to\s+find\s+a\s+whitespace\s+character.\s+A\s+whitespace\s+character\s+can\s+be:

that only escapes the "\s" literal and not the entire string.

Is there an alternative to `Pattern.quote` that escapes single literals instead of the whole string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
String re = Stream.of(input.split("\\s+"))
                  .map(Pattern::quote)
                  .collect(Collectors.joining("\\s+"));
```

This makes sure everything gets quoted (including stuff that otherwise would be interpreted as look-arounds and could cause exponential blowup in match finding), and any user entered whitespace ends up as unquoted `\s+`.

**Example input:**

```
Lorem \\b ipsum \\s dolor (sit) amet.
```

**Output:**

```
\QLorem\E\s+\Q\b\E\s+\Qipsum\E\s+\Q\s\E\s+\Qdolor\E\s+\Q(sit)\E\s+\Qamet.\E
```

Comment: I would probably use such a solution, though I will need to implement a Java 7 version of it. Thanks!