# Java + How can I replace string containing '(' with '\\(' to for pattern.compile regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a the following code

```
StringToSearchIn ="Hello word (Figure 1)"; 
patternString= "word (Figure 1)" 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);       
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(StringToSearchIn);
matcher.find()
```

This is returning 0, as `'( or )'` is not recognized, when I change to 
    `patternString= "word \\(Figure 1\\)"` , is returning the match counter as 1 Is there a way to change my `patternString` to search for `'('` and replace with `'\\('` dynamically before creating a pattern.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it sounds like what you're asking for is a regular expression to match "(Figure 1)"?  Or  '(' followed by anything, followed by ')'?

Comment: Thank you all, it worked with Pattern.quote(String regex);

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Pattern#quote(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(patternString));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the LITERAL flag.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#LITERAL:

> Enables literal parsing of the pattern. When this flag is specified
>   then the input string that specifies the pattern is treated as a
>   sequence of literal characters. Metacharacters or escape sequences in
>   the input sequence will be given no special meaning.

So in your code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.LITERAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern.quote("$5");
```

From this answer:

[How to escape text for regular expression in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Java has built in Pattern conversion.

A Pattern is A compiled representation of a regular expression.
A regular expression, specified as a string, must first be compiled into an instance of this class. The resulting pattern can then be used to create a Matcher object that can match arbitrary character sequences against the regular expression. All of the state involved in performing a match resides in the matcher, so many matchers can share the same pattern.

A typical invocation sequence is thus paternString.replace

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a*b");
 Matcher m = p.matcher("aaaaab");
 boolean b = m.matches();
```

A matches method is defined by this class as a convenience for when a regular expression is used just once. This method compiles an expression and matches an input sequence against it in a single invocation. The statement

```
 boolean b = Pattern.matches("a*b", "aaaaab");
```

If compile is not handling your parenthesis you can do add a method that injects string replacement.

```
patternString = patternString.replace('(', '\('); 
patternString = patternString.replace(')', '\)');
```