# java regex escape all reserved characters

Tags: java, regex

I understand that you can use Pattern.quote to escape characters within a string that is reserved by regex. But I do not understand why the following is not working:

```
String s="and this)";
String ps = "\\b("+Pattern.quote(s)+")\\b";
//String pp = Pattern.quote(pat);
Pattern p=Pattern.compile(ps);
Matcher mm = p.matcher("oh and this) is");

System.out.println(mm.find()); //print false, but expecting true?
```

When `String s= "and this)` is changed to `String s="and this`, i.e., no `)`, it works. How should I change the code so with ")" it also works as expected?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape text for regular expression in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java)

Comment: `\b` matches between `\W` and `\w`. It doesn't match between `)` and `<space>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative look-arounds to check for non-word characters before and after the keyword:

```
String ps = "(?<!\\w)"+Pattern.quote(s)+"(?!\\w)";
```

This way you will still match the `s` as a whole word and it won't be a problem is the keyword has non-word characters at the beginning or end.

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/vYcwdS):

```
String s="and this)";
String ps = "(?<!\\w)"+Pattern.quote(s)+"(?!\\w)";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile(ps);
Matcher mm = p.matcher("oh and this) is");
System.out.println(mm.find());
```

Result: `true`

Comment: `\W` is the negative of `\w`. You can just use that over the negative lookarounds.

Comment: @anubhava: Thank you and merry coming holidays!

Comment: Since @Phylogenesis suggested about using positive lookahead using `\W` I should tell that your current regex using negative lookahead is better approach [as you can see in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/fR1pY9/1) . Otherwise using positive lookaheads it should be [`(?<=\W|^)and this\)(?=\W|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/fR1pY9/2)